# What is the difference between a transaction and a call?

Tags: transactions, contract-design, web3js, json-rpc, contract-invocation

What is the difference between a transaction and a call? In some interfaces, I can interact with contracts via calls or via transactions. What is the difference between the two, and can contracts also do transactions and calls?

Comment: **NOTE** for avoiding confusion: `call` in this question is neither _EVM_ `CALL` opcode nor _Solidity_ `<address>.call()`, which make changes in contract states, but _Web3.js_ API `web3.eth.call()`, which does not make any state changes.

Answer (score 245, accepted):

### Call

A call is a local invocation of a contract function that does not broadcast or publish anything on the blockchain.

It is a read-only operation and will not consume any Ether.  It simulates what would happen in a transaction, but discards all the state changes when it is done.

It is synchronous and the return value of the contract function is returned immediately.

Its web3.js API is [web3.eth.call](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#web3ethcall) and is what's used for [**Solidity `view`, `pure`, `constant` functions**](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/3029/does-soliditys-constant-keyword-do-anything).

Its underlying JSON-RPC is [eth_call](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JSON-RPC#eth_call)

### Transaction

A transaction is broadcasted to the network, processed by miners, and if valid, is published on the blockchain.

It is a write-operation that will affect other accounts, update the state of the blockchain, and consume Ether (unless a miner accepts it with a gas price of zero).

It is asynchronous, because it is possible that no miners will include the transaction in a block (for example, the gas price for the transaction may be too low).  Since it is asynchronous, the immediate **return value of a transaction is always the transaction's hash.**  [To get the "return value" of a transaction](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/6380/how-to-get-values-returned-by-non-constant-transaction-functions) to a function, [Events](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#contract-events) need to be used (unless it's Case4 discussed below).  For ethers.js an example: [listening to contract events using ethers.js?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/87643/listening-to-contract-events-using-ethers-js)

Its web3.js API is [web3.eth.sendTransaction](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#web3ethsendtransaction) and is used if a Solidity function is not marked `constant`.

Its underlying JSON-RPC is [eth_sendTransaction](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JSON-RPC#eth_sendtransaction)

sendTransaction will be used when a verb is needed, since it is clearer than simply transaction.

### Recommendation to Call first, then sendTransaction

Since a sendTransaction costs Ether, it is a good practice to "test the waters" by issuing a *call* first, before the sendTransaction.  This is a free way to debug and estimate if there will be any problems with the sendTransaction, for example if an Out of Gas exception will be encountered.

This "dry-run" usually works well, but in some cases be aware that *call* is an estimate, for example a contract function that returns the previous [blockhash, will return different results](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/266/42) based on when the *call* was performed, and when the transaction is actually mined.

Finally, note that even though a *call* does not consume any Ether, sometimes it may be necessary to specify the actual gas amount for the *call*: the default gas for *call* in clients such as Geth, may [still be insufficient](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/9824/can-solidity-constant-functions-be-arbitrarily-complex) and can still lead to Out of Gas.

### Case4: can contracts create transactions?

There are 4 cases for how a contract function can be invoked.

Here are the 4 cases, and the **first 3 have been covered above**:

1. direct invocation of a contract function, originated with *call*
2. direct invocation of a contract function, originated with sendTransaction
3. contract invocation of a contract function, originated with *call*

**4. contract invocation of a contract function, originated with sendTransaction**

Although Case4 sounds like a contract can "also do transactions", because it's within a transaction, the definition of a transaction is data signed by an External Actor.  Thus Case4 is not a transaction.

From the [Yellow Paper](https://github.com/ethereum/yellowpaper):

> **Transaction**: A piece of data, signed by an External Actor. It
> represents either a Message or a new Autonomous Object. Transactions
> are recorded into each block of the blockchain.

Earlier above, it was stated that Events had to be used to get the return value of a contract function, originated with sendTransaction.  That pertains and is true for Case2.  For Case4, the contract obtains the return value of a contract function directly and can use it.  Here's how the Yellow Paper says it in bold:

> **Message Call**: The act of passing a message from one Account to
> another. If the destination account is associated with non-empty EVM
> Code, then the VM will be started with the state of said Object and
> the Message acted upon. **If the message sender is an Autonomous Object,
> then the Call passes any data returned from the VM operation**

With these definitions from the Yellow Paper, it can be seen that Case4 is a *Message Call* within a transaction (thus state changes), there is **no nesting of transactions**, and that a unit of activity on the Ethereum blockchain is all within **a single transaction that may contain multiple *Message Calls***.

Update: Since *call*ing a function can be ambiguous (is it an eth_call or an eth_sendTransaction?), there is a proposal for [eth_simulateTransaction](https://github.com/ethereum/interfaces/issues/8).

Comment: I would just add some final clarification/conclusion on the potential ambiguity between a web3 call() and a message call() between two contracts? The syntax would look very similar and thus it might be seen that if a contract calls another contract that it works similar to a web3 call, which is not the case. It doesn't simulate it in that environment. It results in state changes.

Comment: Thanks, upvoted and was able to tweak the very last paragraph.

Comment: I nominate this answer as tag wiki for contract-invocation. Feel free to [review and contribute the wiki and excerpt](http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/tags/contract-invocation/info).

Comment: Does any of this change with the "Abstraction" coming in Metropolis?

Comment: I see a message for a view function call in Remix that states "(Cost only applies when called by a contract)". I have an address balance checking function, which makes a call to an external token contract using the Erc20 `balanceOf` method. So in this case, the token contract is in fact called by my smart contract. Will this cost gas as stated, even though the entire process is read-only?

Comment: @GViz A transaction that invokes a `view` or `pure` function will never require payment for gas. You're correct that a simple way to tell is that an entire process that is read-only will not cost gas. Note that [gas is still used by `view` functions](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/9824/can-solidity-constant-functions-be-arbitrarily-complex).

Comment: @eth great point, gas is used temporarily–but not paid–when running view functions to prevent arbitrarily large routines (e.g. infinite loops) from executing.

Comment: is `call` an atomic operation ? other words if the `call` fails somewhere in middle does it rollback?

Comment: @user1870400 `eth_call` does not persist anything: "rollback" is its default behavior.

Comment: @eth when does state updates get written(persisted) into storage? from my understanding reading through code base it looks like state updates get written to storage when the block gets appended to Blockchain until then its all memory. is that correct?

Answer (score 52):

The difference between in a call and a transaction is the following:

- **transactions** are created by your client, signed and broadcasted to the network. They will eventually alter the state of the blockchain, for example, by manipulating balances or values in smart contracts.
- **calls** are transactions executed locally on the user's local machine which alone evaluates the result. These are read-only and fast. They can't change the blockchain in any way because they are never sent to the network. Some examples "read-only/dry run/practice".

Calls are useful for debugging smart contracts as they do not cost transaction fees or gas.

Comment: Searched for a while; this finally explained it for me (I simply put the `constant` modifier on my function and it worked)