# Basic example of interaction between 2 contracts?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, contract-design, contract-invocation

What is a basic example of one contract invoking a method in another (non-calling) contract? Would the address of the contract having that method always need to be hardcoded?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The contract **address does not need to be hardcoded**.

Here's an example:

```
contract C1 {
    function f1() returns(uint) {
        return(10);
    }
}

contract C2 {
    function f2(address addrC1) returns(uint) {
        C1 c1 = C1(addrC1);
        return c1.f1();
    }
}
```

[To quickly test](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/2835/42), paste the code in https://ethereum.github.io/browser-solidity

Then click on "Create" for C1 and C2.  Then in C2's input box for "f2", put the address of C1 in quotes, and click on "f2" to invoke it.

You'll see (10 equals "a" in hexadecimal):

```
Result: "0x000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000a"
Cost: 548 gas.
```

---

EDIT: In case you try to invoke `f1` or `f2` by using web3.js, you will not get the return value unless you explicitly use [`.call`](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/765/what-is-the-difference-between-a-transaction-and-a-call) or add [`constant`](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/3029/does-soliditys-constant-keyword-do-anything) in the Solidity.

Example of ".call": `contractInstance.f2.call(someAddress)`

Example of "constant": `function f2(address addrC1) constant returns(uint)`

Comment: Where in the documentation is it described, that I create a contract object by `Constructor(address)`? Also, would `address` be before or after other, explicitly stated arguments of the constructor? And, are there other implicit arguments to an implicit constructor?

Comment: @TMOTTM In this example, C1 is already deployed.  For an example of creating a contract, which uses `new`, see TokenCreator http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/latest/contracts.html#creating-contracts

Comment: Ok, so `C1` is already deployed. And you would have to write down it's address when it got mined so you can provide it to `f2` as an argument?

Comment: @TMOTTM Yes, an address is needed.

Comment: @eth I was trying to run the above code, but instead of say the integer 10, if I were to return string, i see the error on the online solidity compiler: return argument type inaccessible dynamic type is not implicitly convertible to expected type (type of first return variable) string memory. Any idea how this error can be avoided? - this is at the line in the second contract which calls the first contract.

Comment: @skarred14 Please search for that error on this site, and ask a separate question if still needed.