# Can browser-solidity access contracts values with the in memory tester?

Tags: solidity, dapp-development, remix

I was reading an [interesting answer](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/2836/54) and wanted to make a quick test in [browser-solidity](http://ethereum.github.io/browser-solidity/).

My contract code is below and I'd just like to get the string I passed in the constructor.

```
contract testConstant{
string testString;
// {"_testString":"this is a test"}
function testConstant(string _testString) {
    testString=_testString;
}
function gettestString() public constant returns(string) {
    return testString;
}
}
```

Attached a screenshot, maybe I'm overlooking something but it seems to me the gettestString in blue should return the arg I passed in the constructor : `"this is a test"`

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your [example](https://ethereum.github.io/browser-solidity/#version=soljson-latest.js&optimize=undefined&gist=b16fc69dd685fa91d8cc275d574e63e9) works on
latest Solidity version: 0.3.3-4dc1cb14/Release-Emscripten/clang/Interpreter

> "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000020000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000e7468697320697320612074657374000000000000000000000000000000000000"
>
> Cost: 805 gas. (caveat)
>
> Decoded: string: this is a test