# How to easily share Solidity code so that others can test it?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, dapp-development, ide, remix

Say you have some Solidity code and something doesn't work and you'd like for somebody to take a look at it and do some quick tests.

What is an efficient way to share Solidity code with others?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A very practical way is to use the gist feature of the [browser-solidity](http://chriseth.github.io/browser-solidity/)

1. Paste your code in the browser-solidity, click on the Publish Gist button: [image: publish screenshot]
2. This will create for you a gist, just copy the url: `https://gist.github.com/anonymous/b28692c94b053febe27bbb3692bb31ad`
   [image: gist]
3. Now you can create a direct link in your question to the browser-solidity that other can test instantly: https://chriseth.github.io/browser-solidity/?gist=https://gist.github.com/anonymous/b28692c94b053febe27bbb3692bb31ad

Comment: A quick illustration of testing with browser-solidity: http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/2836/42

Answer (score 2):

Good answer by euri10 already....

If you are just looking for a tool that allows you to send a hunk of code to another person so they can look at it and maybe check your syntax and make some changes, https://codeshare.io/ is a great tool.

It doesn't have Solidity syntax highlighting, but it allows multiple people to work on a single piece of code at the same time, has a short and easy-to-share URL, and is helpful in *some* circumstances.

Namely, it is great when you are sharing some code with a friend or coworker or two. If you want to post to stackexchange or reddit or something else, using a gist is a more efficient and safe way (as not everyone can edit a gist).