# Calling a function doesn't take effect if I update two mappings

Tags: go-ethereum, contract-debugging, contract-invocation

I'm testing a very simple example

```
contract MyNewTest {

Student[] students;
mapping (string => uint) nametonumber;
mapping (uint => string) numbertoname;
uint counter;

struct Student
{
    string name;
    uint num;
}

function addStudent(string _name)
{
    uint _id;
    _id = students.length++;
    students[_id].name = _name;
    students[_id].num = _id;
    numbertoname[_id] = _name;
    nametonumber[_name] = _id;
}

function getLength() constant
returns (uint)
{
    return students.length;
}

function getStudentNumber(string name) constant
returns (uint)
{
    return nametonumber[name];
}

function getStudentName(uint number) constant
returns (string)
{
    return numbertoname[number];
}

function getStudentAtPosition(uint x) constant
returns (string)
{
    return students[x].name;
}

function getStudentNumberAtPosition(uint x) constant
returns (uint)
{
    return students[x].num;
}
}
```

Am running a private local blockchain with mining turned on.

I tried to call

```
mynewtest.addStudent("Joe")
```

then

```
mynewtest.getLength()
```

it returns Zero although I added a new student.

However, inside the **newStudent** function if I remove either

```
numbertoname[_id] = _name;
```

or

```
nametonumber[_name] = _id;
```

everything works fine and when I add a student and do

```
mynewtest.getLength()
```

I get 1.

is there a constraint that I can't update two mappings in the same function?
Does this code work for anybody?

Answer (score 2):

I [quickly tested in browser-solidity](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/2836/42) your code and was able to `addStudent`.

Your transaction to `addStudent` probably does not have enough gas: if you're using web3.js `mynewtest.addStudent("Joe", {gas:2000000 ...}, ...)`

Comment: Advice for beginners: most problems occur because of a lack of gas.

Comment: @bortzmeyer I agree wholeheartedly.