# How are solidity integer overflows handled?

Tags: solidity, overflow

**uint8 x** = 255;

**x** += 10;

Is **x** going to be 0 or 9?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`x` will be 9.

Use this code and [How to quickly test a Solidity function?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/2835/how-to-quickly-test-a-solidity-function)

```
contract C {
    function test() returns(uint) {
        uint8 x = 255;
        x += 10;
        return x;
    }
}
```

> Decoded:  uint256: 9

Comment: You're a life saver! Thank you, good sir! You're like a kind wizard that makes dumb contracts smart))