# Solidity Browser Compiler — Error: Assertion failed

Tags: remix

Here's the code:

```
contract C {
    function a(uint x){}
}
```

I try to call `C.a(1000000000000000000);`

and get an error:

```
Error encoding arguments: Error: Assertion failed
```

while `C.a(100000000);` is perfectly fine

What's the problem there?

Answer (score 5):

The uint is too big for a native Javascript Number, so the Solidity Browser needs the input in quotes ("1000000000000000000") so that it can read the input as a string and manipulate it as a [BigNumber](https://github.com/MikeMcl/bignumber.js).

Thanks for asking and I added it to [How to quickly test a Solidity function?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/2835/how-to-quickly-test-a-solidity-function)

For easy testing, I tested with this code:

```
contract C {
    function a(uint x) returns(uint) { return x; }
}
```