# Can't transfer more than 9007000000000000 tokens at once?

Tags: tokens, balances

I'm using the [Zeppelin](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/zeppelin-solidity/blob/master/contracts/) ERC20 code and I can't seem to `transfer` more than 9007000000000000 token "cents" at a time.

Address `a` has a `balanceOf` 1000000000000000000000000 (10 million tokens * 1000000000000000000 (because I'm using 18 decimals)). However, when I `transfer('b', 1000000000000000000000000)` from account `a`, Remix says: `Error encoding arguments: Error: Assertion failed`.

It gives me the same error for 100000000000000000000000, 10000000000000000000000, 1000000000000000000000, all the way down to 9007000000000000 (which it lets me transfer; it fails with slightly more (9008000000000000)).

`balanceOf` for both accounts checks out correctly afterwards.

Also, when I comment out the `assert` lines in `SafeMath`, Remix gives me the same error. There are no other `assert`ions in the code.

What's going wrong here?

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.15;

library SafeMath {

  function sub(uint256 a, uint256 b) internal constant returns (uint256) {
    assert(b <= a);
    return a - b;
  }

  function add(uint256 a, uint256 b) internal constant returns (uint256) {
    uint256 c = a + b;
    assert(c >= a);
    return c;
  }
}



using SafeMath for uint;

mapping(address => uint256) balances;

function balanceOf(address _owner) constant returns (uint256 balance) {
  return balances[_owner];
}

function transfer(address _to, uint256 _value) returns (bool) {
   balances[msg.sender] = balances[msg.sender].sub(_value);
   balances[_to] = balances[_to].add(_value);
   Transfer(msg.sender, _to, _value);
   return true;
 }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out large numbers need to be [wrapped in quotes](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/8041/solidity-browser-compiler-error-assertion-failed) when using Remix, because of Javascript limitations, so `transfer('a', '100000000000000000000000') works.