# How does the delegatecall method work to call to another contract's method?

Tags: solidity, contract-invocation, library, delegatecall

I'm trying to figure out how to use the `delegatecall` method on a contract address in a contract to call a function in a separate contract.

I know Libraries are the higher level interface to use but I want to understand the lower level actions and behaviors.

If someone could provide some good examples of a contract using `delegatecall` to another contract's functions, that would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Here is a snippet of `D` using `delegatecall` on `E` from [Difference between CALL, CALLCODE and DELEGATECALL](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/3667/difference-between-call-callcode-and-delegatecall)

```
contract D {
  uint public n;
  address public sender;

  function delegatecallSetN(address _e, uint _n) {
    _e.delegatecall(bytes4(keccak256("setN(uint256)")), _n); // D's storage is set, E is not modified 
  }
}

contract E {
  uint public n;
  address public sender;
  function setN(uint _n) {
    n = _n;
    sender = msg.sender;
  }
}
```

When an address C invokes `delegatecallSetN`, D's `sender` will be set to C (E is not modified).  Whatever `msg.value` is part of the invocation, will also be the value of `msg.value` inside `setN`.

You can [quickly test above in Solidity Browser](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/2835/how-to-quickly-test-a-solidity-function).

For libraries see the [Solidity docs](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/latest/contracts.html#libraries).

Comment: I was able to get it working though I could not get it working for strings or for bytes32

Comment: I think it should work the same for `bytes32`.  For `string` and `bytes`, I'm not sure and a separate question is probably needed.

Comment: `D.delcallCfunc(addressOfE, 10);` is it the correct way to call it? Could `addressOfE` be a string? @eth

Comment: @Avatar If you're using an example like the answer, the way your calling seems consistent, but `addressOfE` can't be a string since string doesn't have a `delegatecall` member.  It's probably easier to stick to [libraries](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/latest/contracts.html#libraries) instead of "plain" delegatecall.

Comment: Does this work with enums ?

Comment: @eth in that case, E and D and are stored at the same address, isn’t it ?

Comment: @user2284570 Question is unclear. Each address only has 1 contract.