# Question about how to have interacting contracts

Tags: go-ethereum, solidity

Let's say I'm doing a crowdsale, but instead of selling a set amount of tokens I'm just giving tokens away at a pre-set price. In other words, my token has the following functoin:

```
function give(address giveToAddress,uint amount)onlyPermittedContracts{
    balanceOf[giveToAddress]+= amount;
}
```

Now I only want permitted contracts to execute this function. So I add the following modifier:

```
modifier onlyPermittedContracts{
    if(permissibleContracts[msg.sender]!=true){
        throw;
    }
    else if(permissibleContracts[msg.sender]==true){
        _;
    }
    throw;
}
```

And a way for the owner to add permitted contracts:

```
function setPermissibleContract(address _contactAddress)onlyOwner{
    if (permissibleContracts[_contactAddress] == true){
        permissibleContracts[_contactAddress]==false;
    }
    else{
        permissibleContracts[_contactAddress]==true;
    }
}
```

Then, in my crowdsale contract I add the following code:

```
token public rewardToken = myTokenAddress; //(this is set in constructor) 
function () payable{
    if (saleClosed)
        {throw;}
    else{
        uint amount = msg.value;
        balanceOf[msg.sender] = amount;
        amountRaised += amount;
        rewardToken.give(msg.sender, amount / tokenPriceInEther)
    }
}
```

My question is whether this is the proper way to interact between tokens and contracts.

Additionally, when I create "token public tokenReward" how does ethereum know that my token is a token as opposed to any other type of contract?

Answer (score 1):

In general, the architecture is fine. There are small glitches, probably the most important one is the line:

```
balanceOf[msg.sender] = amount;
```

as a user may overwrite his account by performing more that one transaction.

I'd also recommend using a [safe math](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/zeppelin-solidity/blob/master/contracts/math/SafeMath.sol) library to check for over and underflows.

This funcion is a bit misleading. It's better to have two separate one to grant and revoke permissions:

```
function setPermissibleContract(address _contactAddress)onlyOwner{
```

Your modifier can be simplified:

```
modifier onlyPermittedContracts{
    if(permissibleContracts[msg.sender]) {
        _;
    } else {
       throw;
    }
}
```

> Additionally, when I create "token public tokenReward" how does
>   ethereum know that my token is a token as opposed to any other type of
>   contract?

The usual approach is to define an interface and cast the token address to this interface. If you are interested in the detailed answer how one contract may execute a method from the other one please check this [answer](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/8120/how-does-the-delegatecall-method-work-to-call-to-another-contracts-method).

Comment: With regards to the "token" question I'm asking more because in my token contract I never specify that it is a token anywhere. So what is the significance behind using a token variable?

Comment: To answer that correctly I need to see where do you define the identifier "token" in your code. Is it import statement or inline interface?

Comment: Oh I see. It is: contract token { function transfer(address receiver, uint amount){  } }