# Is it possible to get both address of the user and the contract when delegate call is used?

Tags: solidity, delegatecall

When the user calls the delegatecallSetN function of contract D below, the msg.sender in contract E is the address of the user (as shown in this [example](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/8120/how-does-the-delegatecall-method-work-to-call-to-another-contracts-method#)).

```
contract D {
  uint public n;
  address public sender;

  function delegatecallSetN(address _e, uint _n) {
    _e.delegatecall(bytes4(sha3("setN(uint256)")), _n); // D's storage is set, E is not modified 
  }
}

contract E {
  uint public n;
  address public sender;
  function setN(uint _n) {
    n = _n;
    sender = msg.sender;
  }
}
```

My question is:
How can we check in contract E that the call was done through contract D and not directly through the user?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37644395/how-to-find-out-if-an-ethereum-address-is-a-contract .. Please look at Manuel Aráoz Answer.. I think you can make use of Iscontract function mentioned and check only Contract  D has invoked Contract E and not by user.

Answer (score 2):

Should work if you use tx.origin. However this is usually advised against.

Answer (score 1):

See this answer, https://stackoverflow.com/a/40939341/7482810

using some EVM assembly code to get the address' code size:

```
 function isContract(address addr) returns (bool) {
 uint size;
 assembly { size := extcodesize(addr) }
 return size > 0;}
```

As to why this function works, see https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/14016/19016