# Change ERC20 Transfer function to account for contract as sender

Tags: solidity, truffle, erc-20

I have a contract we will call A that uses the transfer function from an ERC20 contract we will call B through an interface.  However, the transfer function will not work as expected because in the call from user -> A -> B the msg.sender is now the contract address of A and not the user's address anymore.

I can think of two immediate ways to solve this.

1. Pass the original msg.sender (user's address) as a param to the transfer function
2. Change msg.sender in contract B's transfer function to tx.origin

However both of these solutions modify the ERC20 token standard contract which I am not sure if that is good practice.

I can see how this could be a common issue devs run into. Should I implement one of the above solutions even though it changes the standard contract? If not, then how should I solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The proper way to do this is with the `approve` and `transferFrom` workflow. The EOA would `approve` the contract to transfer the tokens, and then call the function on the contract which would use `tranferFrom` instead of `transfer`

Answer (score -1):

This seems like the use of `delegatecall()` via a proxy pattern is what you're looking for.

With Delegate call, **you pass along the original sender to the next contract**. However, this can expose you to security risks to the calling contract. i.e. in your scenario contract B as you are exposing Contract A's storage to Contract B.

There are other posts that explain how to use such e.g. 
[Difference between CALL, CALLCODE and DELEGATECALL](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/3667/difference-between-call-callcode-and-delegatecall)

[How does the delegatecall method work to call to another contract's method?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/8120/how-does-the-delegatecall-method-work-to-call-to-another-contracts-method)

Great Blog: https://blog.gnosis.pm/solidity-delegateproxy-contracts-e09957d0f201

Comment: This will use the callers storage rather than the callee. `msg.sender` is correct but the updates to balances won't be saved to storage associated with the token contract.

Comment: @MrYellow so do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: @JonathanScialpi There is `approve`/`transferFrom` pattern. Also several draft standards coming up for adding a callback to inform a contract of tokens being sent. ERC223, ERC677, ERC827