# msg.sender problem for calling ERC20 token contract from another contract returns contract address

Tags: solidity, transactions, tokens, erc-20

when i am going to call approve function of erc20 contract.log prints tokenOwner and tokenSpender address same which is contract address msg.sender returns contract address. but i want tokenWner = caller address and tokenSpender = contract address please help.

THis is erc20 method

```
 function approve(address spender, uint256 tokens) public returns (bool success) {
    allowed[msg.sender][spender] = tokens;
   emit Approval(msg.sender, spender, tokens);

    return true;
}
```

And this is my contract method that is calling token method

```
 function approve(address token, uint256 _value) public returns (bool) {
 return ERC20Interface(token).approve(this, _value);
}
```

Comment: post your javescript code, and maybe the approve funtion of your smart contract

Comment: @MajdTL here is my code in erc20 (msg.sender) become my contract address

Comment: try to use delegated calls, however that is not the best praxis, has risk, and the owner of the token should call the first approve method directly, both are public functions. https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/8120/how-does-the-delegatecall-method-work-to-call-to-another-contracts-method

Comment: Already i tried with delegate call it working fine with approve. but when i call allowance it returning me 0 approval.

Comment: you call allowance with delegated call? delegate call does not provide a return value or exception

Comment: No i called allowance method normally with deployed contract

Comment: then your delegated call did not work, as i said you cannot see an error if its happened

Comment: yes so how can i transfer tokens in that case. Because token contract has conditions

Comment: can you upload your code somewhere  in Github with a read me and I will take look at it at the weekend

Comment: https://github.com/Love3119/Escrow.git you can check here my code any help will be appreciated

Comment: PLEASE DONT DO THIS (cause it is the worst hackable thing you can do in solidity). but the only way to do that is to change the function approve in ERC20Basic to allowed[tx.origin][delegate] = numTokens; and do not change anything in myContract. as I said dont do that and redesign your contracts and make the owner call direct the approve in Erc20Basic.

Comment: This is right way? ERC20Basic to allowed[tx.origin][delegate] = numTokens;  i want to transfer already deployed tokens. Can i do this with my code. and how owner call direct approve function.

Comment: no this will not work with normal deployed tokens cause they have msg.sender and not tx.origin.  The Owner should call the method approve in the ERC20Basic directly and not through another approve method in another smart contract

Comment: Yay i got it. and thankyou so much.It is  working with tx.origin. but i have one question. if i want to transfer any erc20 token so how can i to call approve method directly without my contract interaction.

Comment: please don't use tx.origin, it is just a trick and not used in standards erc20 tokens. how the owner was going to call approve in your contract, are you using web3js to interact with the contract?

Comment: will use but right now i am testing it on remix

Comment: how can i call other tokens approve method without my contract interaction please let me know. because i am new in solidity

Comment: That has nothing with solidity to do, You can do that later with java script and web3js, you get the instance of erc20contract by its address and abi and make the sender send a transaction to call the method approve with parameters I. That contract

Comment: thankyou so much now i have clarity what i have to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The users who is spending tokens is the one to approve the contract.

The contract cannot appoint itself to spend tokens from someone else's wallet.

Hope it helps.

Comment: you are right. but when i call approve function from my contract than msg.sender should be caller address but right now it is contract address. and i want to approve my contract from caller.and that caller already have tokens.

Comment: The `msg.sender` should be your contract, in that case, which is not what you want, because msg.sender is always the inner-most caller, which is your contract. The caller needs to approve directly, not through your contract.

Comment: in that case what should i do?

Comment: I suspect maybe you misunderstand the flow. The user calls approve in the token contract and then calls a function in your contract to do something and pull the payment. The two steps on the user side can be coordinated by the user-facing UI.

Comment: i want to use already available tokens and i don't have any code of that tokens so how can i directly call token approve without my contract interaction. please let me know.

Comment: @lovechawda you have the address of that erc20 token contract and the abi is always the same cause it is a standard