# Does Solidity's constant keyword do anything?

Tags: solidity, transactions, web3js

It seems that the purpose of `function foo() constant {}` is to indicate that a function does not change the contract's state. And yet, as it states [here](http://solidity.readthedocs.org/en/latest/frequently-asked-questions.html#what-is-the-difference-between-a-function-marked-constant-and-one-that-is-not), the compiler doesn't actually enforce this. So for the time being, is `constant` simply an unenforced convention? A way to let contract readers know that this function *shouldn't* change state?

In reality, this `bar` function works just fine:

```
contract Foo {
  uint x;

  function bar(uint y) constant {
    x = y;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As noted in the question, `constant` isn't enforced by the compiler yet.

But it is used by web3.js to do a `call` instead of `sendTransaction`.

So in the question's example, `contractInstance.bar(2)` would run the equivalent of `contractInstance.bar.call(2, ...)`.

If `bar` was not marked `constant`, `contractInstance.bar.sendTransaction(2, ...)` would be executed instead.

See [Contract Methods](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#contract-methods) and [Difference between a transaction and call](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/765/42) for more information.