# Reading a uint from a mapping keeps returning a random address

Tags: solidity, web3js, dapp-development, mapping

I am new to Solidity. I am facing an issue in a simple operation of storing and retrieving data from mapping (uint=> address).

I have defined a simple contract:

```
contract test {
    mapping (uint => address) public testmap;

    function add_to_map  (uint _key, address _val) public{
        testmap[_key] = _val;
    }
    function get_from_map(uint _key) returns (address){
        return testmap[_key];
    }   
}
```

In html, I am trying to do:

```
function createTestContract(){
    var test = testContract.at("0xc383dfb5fc71ff1bb2bbadb812229681fb7a8e3c");
    test.add_to_map(1, "0x12ca4a043753cd5537af99ad314a299962238ed2");       
    console.log('Key: 1'  + ' address: ' + test.get_from_map(1));
}
```

As output I am expecting address - 0x12ca4a043753cd5537af99ad314a299962238ed2 which I am stored against key 1. However, it is returning some random address in the console log.

```
Key: 1 address: 0x07824f2f2a330dd2e260437af299800175dc2642a63c71a5f824cee54eae2264
```

I am using private chain on AlethZero. Appreciate if anyone can help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to specify [`constant`](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/3029/42) so that you get the return value of a `call`:

`function get_from_map(uint _key) constant returns (address)`.

Without constant, `test.get_from_map(1)` is a `sendTransaction` which always returns a transaction hash.  See [What is the difference between a transaction and a call?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/765/42)

Comment: Thank you @eth. It is clear now and it worked. Many thanks.