# atom-ethereum-interface returning different outputs from browser-solidity

Tags: go-ethereum, solidity, contract-development, contract-invocation, remix

I'm working on a proof-of-concept "email server" dapp and am getting different behavior in [atom-ethereum-interface](https://atom.io/packages/atom-ethereum-interface) vs. [browser-solidity](https://ethereum.github.io/browser-solidity/#version=soljson-v0.4.2+commit.af6afb04.js)

I'm running a private blockchain in a Docker container with my own nodes successfully mining all my transactions.

Here's my solidity code:

```
// EmailServer.sol

pragma solidity ^0.4.2;

contract EmailServer {
  address owner;
  bytes[] inbox;

  function EmailServer() {
    owner = msg.sender;
  }

  function addEmail(bytes x) constant {
    inbox.push(x);
  }

  function getInboxCount() returns (uint count) {
    return inbox.length;
  }

  function getEmails() returns (bytes email) {
    bytes emailsOutput;
    uint inboxCount = getInboxCount();
    uint emailLength;

    if (inboxCount == 0) {
      throw;
    }

    emailsOutput.push('[');
    for (uint i = 0; i < inboxCount; i++) {
      emailLength = inbox[i].length;
      emailsOutput.push('"');
      for (uint j = 0; j < emailLength; j++) {
        emailsOutput.push(inbox[i][j]);
      }
      emailsOutput.push('"');

      if (i < inboxCount - 1) {
        emailsOutput.push(',');
      }
    }
    emailsOutput.push(']');

    return emailsOutput;
  }

  function getOwner() returns (address) {
    return owner;
  }

  // Kill contract and return funds to owner
  function kill() {
    if (msg.sender == owner) {
      suicide(owner);
    }
  }
}
```

This contract correctly compiles and deploys on both atom-ethereum-interface and browser-solidity.

In both places you can run `addEmail("QmZULkCELmmk5XNfCgTnCyFgAVxBRBXyDHGGMVoLFLiXEN")` and it works fine.

But then in browser-solidity when you run `getInboxCount()` you get a `result` of: `0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001` which decodes to a `uint` of `1`.

When you run `getInboxCount()` in atom-ethereum-interface, the `contract output` is `0xab979d45598f6f3a548113f896a8d24681e9d231a5e3d614cae4b0dcee19e578` and is different every time you run the function. It doesn't seem to decode to anything.

Likewise with any of the other functions. In browser-solidity, it seems to work fine, but in atom-ethereum-interface it returns something I can't seem to decode to anything meaningful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use [`constant`](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/3029/does-soliditys-constant-keyword-do-anything) label:

```
function getInboxCount() constant returns (uint count) {
    return inbox.length;
}
```

Without it, web3.js / atom-ethereum-interface is giving you a transaction hash, like [Reading a uint from a mapping keeps returning a random address](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/4155/reading-a-uint-from-a-mapping-keeps-returning-a-random-address)

Without `constant`, invoking `getInboxCount` with web3.js is a `sendTransaction` which always returns a transaction hash. See [What is the difference between a transaction and a call?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/765/42)

Comment: Thank you, this helps a lot and has fixed a couple of the methods. The method it doesn't fix is `getEmails()` which is going through the `bytes[]`, and going through each `bytes` and decoding each letter, to return a serialized array. This is erroring with `Uncaught BigNumber Error: new BigNumber() not a base 16 number`. I'm sure there's a better way to return an array?

Comment: Returning an array, and the error when returning bytes, might be best asked as 2 separate questions.  Also, try a simpler function that returns `bytes`.