# What's the difference in the ways of calling a contract function?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, web3js, contract-invocation

After I get an instance of a contract, there are 3 ways to call the contract function below:

1.`testInstance.testfunc({from:eth.accounts[0]})`
2.`testInstance.testfunc.sendTransaction({from:eth.accounts[0]})`
3.`testInstance.testfunc.call({from:eth.accounts[0]})`

What's the difference from each other?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're using web3.js:

1. If `testfunc` in Solidity is labelled with [`constant`](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/3029/does-soliditys-constant-keyword-do-anything), it will behave as a call #3.  Otherwise, it will behave as a transaction #2.
2. is an explicit transaction that will be broadcasted to the network and potentially mined into a block.  The return value will always be a transaction hash.  This costs ether (computed by [*gas used* X *gas price*](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/10940/42)).
3. is an explicit local invocation of `testfunc` that does not broadcast or publish anything on the blockchain.  The return value is determined by the Solidity code of `testfunc`.  This does not cost ether (though [*gas* is still used](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/10906/who-gets-the-fee-from-contract-call)).

For a detailed explanation see
[What is the difference between a transaction and a call?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/765/what-is-the-difference-between-a-transaction-and-a-call)