# Best way for web3 to receive data from function return?

Tags: contract-development, web3js, dapp-development, json-rpc, metamask

Now I'm trying to delelop my first Dapp (using Metamask plugin). everything is going to be all right, but I can't get one thing: **Is it possible to receive return from function, using Web3 (not JS VM!)**

For example, I have a simple contract like this:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.0;

contract test {
    int32 data = 123;

    function getData() returns (int32) {
        return data;
    }
}
```

When I'm calling `getData()` with JS virtual machine, it works fine:

[image: remix]

But with selected `Inject web3` (Metamask) it returns information about new transaction, instead of `123`

[image: remix_web3]

I also can't receive any data from the JS console (Metamask):

[image]

Comment: The last example in the JS console looks like it should work.  Maybe this question needs to focus on that part.

Comment: @eth Yep, it works fine, but I get txn hash instead of 123, as expected

Comment: Sorry, I misread the console output as error being undefined and data as null.  The txn hash is returned because a transaction was issued by web3 instead of a "call" (hope you saw the question that asks about the difference).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the question, the simplest is to make `getData` [constant](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/3029/does-soliditys-constant-keyword-do-anything) as:

`function getData() constant returns (int32)`

Another option is to use an event:
[How to get return values when function with argument is called?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/3285/how-to-get-return-values-when-function-with-argument-is-called)

Comment: Adding `constant` modifier solved all, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

Did you try using the call function asynchronously:

```
contract.getData.call().then(function(result) {
  console.log(result);
});
```

Comment: I've had pretty good success using Promise.promisifyAll (after contract instantiation) so you can use actual return values (Promises) instead of callbacks, if return values are important to you.