# Why do we need to specify constant in the return value

Tags: solidity

Referring to the constant below:

```
  function totalSupply() constant returns (uint256 totalSupply);
```

Comment: Related: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/3029/does-soliditys-constant-keyword-do-anything

Answer (score 5):

From Solidity docs:

> Functions can be declared constant in which case they promise not to modify the state.

If a function doesn't modify the state of blockchain (simply getters), you should add `constant` to function definition.

Answer (score 3):

The main reason to do so is to indicate [web3js](https://github.com/ethereum/web3.js/) (or any other json-rpc client) to use [eth_call](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JSON-RPC#eth_call) function instead of [eth_sendTransaction](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JSON-RPC#eth_sendtransaction).

The `constant` modifier needs to be added manually by a programmer and compiler won't enforce adding it even if the state is not being modified (read details in [docs](http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/contracts.html#constant-functions) ).

Remember that you are `not charged` for calling `constant` methods but only from `off-chain context` (like using web3js client). If you call them inside any other contract method you will still be charged.

Answer (score 1):

> Why do we need to specify constant in the return value

Just to be pedantic: the *return value* isn't being declared as constant, the function is, as the document snippet in the other answer has pointed out.

Answer (score 1):

Adding constant you're telling to the compiler that this function is going to perform only read actions (calls instead of transactions), and calls have no gas costs.
So if you have to set up a getter function just add the property constant.

```
function getBalance() constant returns(uint) {
    return balance;
}
```