# Why does this smart contract compile?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, remix

Can someone please help me understand why this smart contract compiles in ReMix?

What is the purpose of the word `constant` if it doesn't preclude the code from changing the state? I'm looking for a technical answer that explains why Solidity allows this, not just says *"that's the way it is."*

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.9;

contract ShouldNotCompile {
    address addr;
    function getSender() constant returns (address) {
        addr = msg.sender;
        return addr;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As documentation [states](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/security-considerations.html?highlight=constant#minor-details), enforcement of `constant` is simply not (yet?) implemented. It seems weird for me as well, I suppose, the devs just think this issue is of a lower priority.

Comment: You're correct. This question also seems to be a duplicate of https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/3029/does-soliditys-constant-keyword-do-anything