# Eris Industries tutorial: Call contract object from other contract

Tags: contract-invocation, eris-industries

In the [Eris Industries tutorial](https://docs.erisindustries.com/tutorials/solidity/solidity-1/), they present a banking and fund management contract system.

The `FundManager` controls the `bank` contract. I don't understand the following line from the `deposit` function used to check if the function call was successful:

```
bool success = Bank(bank).deposit.value(msg.value)(msg.sender);
```

Why `Bank(bank)` and what is it? The `FundManager` has an `address bank` attribute, instantiated by the constructor.

So, essentially, my question is:

```
Bank(bank): Get a reference object of type `Bank` at address `bank`
Bank(bank).deposit: call the `deposit` function on that object
Bank(bank).deposit.value(msg.value): What is happening here and what is returned?
Bank(bank).deposit.value(msg.value)(msg.sender): What is happening here?
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `FundManager` constructor creates a new `Bank` contract object...

```
bank = new Bank();
```

...and stores its address in this variable:

```
// This holds a reference to the current bank contract.
    address bank;
```

When the `FundManager`'s `deposit` function is called, it calls the `Bank` contract using its address, as explained in [this](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/1599/basic-example-of-interaction-between-2-contracts?rq=1) previous thread:

```
Bank(bank)...
```

In full, the call is:

```
bool success = Bank(bank).deposit.value(msg.value)(msg.sender);
```

Where the `deposit` function in the `Bank` contract is defined as:

```
// This will take the value of the transaction and add to the senders account.
function deposit(address customer) returns (bool res)
```

The `customer` address parameter equates to the `msg.sender` passed by the call in `FundManager`.

**Edit:**

> Bank(bank).deposit.value(msg.value): What is happening here and what
>   is returned?

I don't think this is a valid call by itself. It'd probably complain about a missing argument.

> Bank(bank).deposit.value(msg.value)(msg.sender): What is happening here?

`Bank(bank).deposit()` is an *external function call*: it's calling a function in a different contract.

The parameter for the `deposit` function in the second contract is `address customer`, so we'd expect the call in the first contract to be:

```
Bank(bank).deposit(msg.sender)
```

...where `msg.sender` equates to `address customer`. So far so clear.

However, [for external function calls](http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/latest/control-structures.html?highlight=.value#external-function-calls), if we want the *second* contract to know the original value of `msg.value` from the first contract, then we must explicitly pass it. The reason being (from [this](http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/latest/units-and-global-variables.html?highlight=msg.value#block-and-transaction-properties) page in the Solidity docs (part-way down)):

> The values of all members of msg, including msg.sender and msg.value
>   can change for every external function call. This includes calls to
>   library functions.

To explicitly pass the value we need a `value(msg.value)` in there as well, which by convention goes before the actual parameter of the function we're calling:

```
          +------------------------------------+
          |                                    |
          |                                    V
Bank(bank).deposit    .value(msg.value)      (msg.sender)
                            ^
                            |
                  shove it in the middle
```

Comment: Helps, but I still dont understand the second half of the call. Adjusted the question.

Comment: I updated the answer with more details. Let me know if it's still not clear.

Comment: Sort of, but that's me.. Is there a reason not to just define the signature as `deposit(address customer, uint value)` and then to call it using `Bank(bank).deposit(msg.sender, value_to_deposit)`?

Comment: `msg.value` is a [special variable](http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/latest/units-and-global-variables.html?highlight=msg.value#special-variables-and-functions) which you wouldn't normally need to pass around - you'd just call it from within the contract. When making an external call to a different contract, we need to pass it as a parameter. (The second contract may have a different value of the special variable.) They've perhaps implemented it this way to make the signatures for `deposit()` in both contracts match, or to show different features of the language.

Comment: But no - I can't see any real reason for not implementing with two arguments.

Comment: @Richard Horrocks I have been trying to compile the eris contract tutorial using native solidity compiler on geth console. after removing all new line characters and removing comments, and compiling, i get the error: Expected primary expression. Any suggestions?