# How do I filter an event by the hash of the transaction that generated the event?

Tags: dapp-development, events, logs, filters, oo7js

I read the following in [Andreas Olofsson's](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/users/542/andreas-olofsson) [answer](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/2059/how-to-read-responses-from-calls-to-contract-methods-made-using-web3-js/2096#2096):

> Events can also be filtered by the hash of the transaction that generated the event

Would someone please post an example of how to do this with `oo7-parity.js`, `web3.js`  or `ethjs` ...

I've not found any particularly helpful examples in the the docs

Comment: Does anyone know if this is possible with the ethers.js library? Their docs show event handling in their Low-level API (https://docs.ethers.io/ethers.js/api-advanced.html#low-level-api), but it's not clear if it's possible to specify a contract to watch.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So this can be done by watching for contract events, optionally from a specified sender, and then filtering the result by the transaction hash. Here's an example using `web3.js`:

```
const Web3 = require('web3');
const web3 = new Web3();
web3.setProvider(new web3.providers.HttpProvider('http://127.0.0.1:8545'));

const multiSigWalletFactoryAddress = '0xF935...c5B9F1f';
const MultiSigWalletFactoryABI = [{"constant":true,"...","type":"event"}];
const MultiSigWalletFactory = web3.eth.contract(MultiSigWalletFactoryABI);
const multiSigWalletFactoryInstance = MultiSigWalletFactory.at(multiSigWalletFactoryAddress);

const event = multiSigWalletFactoryInstance.ContractInstantiation({sender: '0x72D0...ef412F'});

event.watch(function(error, result) {
  if (error) {
    console.log('error', error);
  } else {
    // here the transaction hash can be checked and filtered on
    console.log('result.transactionHash', result.transactionHash);
    // here the arguments from the Event can be read
    console.log('result.args', result.args);
  }
});
```

Docs: [web3.eth.filter](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#web3ethfilter), [contract-events](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#contract-events)

To help others that might stumble over the same gotcha, one reason I was struggling with getting this to work was because I was testing https://kovan.infura.io/ and didn't realise that [eth_newfilter](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JSON-RPC#eth_newfilter) is not one of their [supported json rpc methods](https://infura.io/docs/#supported-json-rpc-methods)