# How to get the transaction hash once it is mined?

Tags: web3js, javascript, confirmations, raw-transaction

In JavaScript (web3.js), how do I get the transaction-hash corresponding to a function executed in my smart contract?

Comment: See http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/3285/how-to-get-return-values-when-function-with-argument-is-called .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you send a transaction to a contract function, you get back the transaction hash:

```
var txHash = myContract.myFunction(param1, { from: you });
```

If there is a transaction that you need to find, look into your sender address at etherscan.io.