# Get the result of token transfer transaction in geth

Tags: go-ethereum, transactions, tokens, rpc

There is a way to get the result of a token transfer operation in Parity https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/9009

Is there a way to do it in geth by RPC?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i'm guessing you want to check if the transaction was successful?

rpc: `eth_getTransactionReceipt`

https://wiki.parity.io/JSONRPC-eth-module#eth_gettransactionreceipt

web3: `web3.eth.getTransactionReceipt('tx-hash-here')`

https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.0/web3-eth.html#gettransactionreceipt

Comment: Thanks for the response, but I meant something else. Sometimes a transaction can be successful but the sender's balance lacks the provided amount of tokens. So, despite the correct execution of the transaction itself, the transfer of tokens still doesn't happen. E.g [this transfer of HT tokens](https://etherscan.io/tx/0xddb143957b3af5efc5d4c8c38cce501bd95d7532a16dafb1a0373a930826e791)

Comment: yes, you can see if the transaction is successful by getting the transaction receipt. the `status` field will be `0x1` (true) if they had enough to send or `0x0` (false) if it failed for some reason, like not having enough tokens.

Comment: But what about the aforementioned transaction? It has the status 0x1 but the tokens clearly weren't transferred (the requested amount of tokens are orders of magnitude more than issuance)

Comment: that looks to be an issue with the specific contract