# Calling Smart Contract whoAmI function

Tags: contract-development, blockchain, contract-invocation

Having a smart contract mined on testnet at address 0x5a6661c75df7de88ba74437a6dc372ccfa72a564 with the following function:

```
    function whoAmI() constant returns (address) {
        return msg.sender;
    }
```

should return caller always. And that's what I am trying to verify. I works ok when calling synchronously from geth console like this:

```
// creation of contract object
var aContract = web3.eth.contract([{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"totalSupply","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[],"name":"kill","outputs":[],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[{"name":"account","type":"address"}],"name":"queryBalanceOf","outputs":[{"name":"balance","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[{"name":"","type":"address"}],"name":"balanceOf","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"initialSupply","type":"uint256"}],"name":"MyToken","outputs":[],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"_to","type":"address"},{"name":"_value","type":"uint256"}],"name":"transfer","outputs":[],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"whoAmI","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"address"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"payable":false,"type":"fallback"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"name":"from","type":"address"},{"indexed":true,"name":"to","type":"address"},{"indexed":false,"name":"value","type":"uint256"}],"name":"Transfer","type":"event"}]);

// initiate contract for an address
var sc = aContract.at('0x5a6661c75df7de88ba74437a6dc372ccfa72a564');

// calling function
sc.whoAmI();
    "0x47978a69f410d0f61850c92acdb0d4c464d70937"
```

The problem comes when trying to call it asynchronously from another account like this:

```
sc.whoAmI.sendTransaction({from:"0x3b877e80b5c0b29d88f3768ed4292b35fdd93a9d"});
txHash => "0x5fc3f7454d558ad4bd01294448b45bc7072b46958375fafe32e277a770d48e90"
```

Where is the output of the transaction stored? Trying this:

```
eth.getTransactionReceipt("0x5fc3f7454d558ad4bd01294448b45bc7072b46958375fafe32e277a770d48e90")
{
  blockHash: "0xa19553677ede1d1eed791d1658a4229629346f90db5907c14c915dda13926df9",
  blockNumber: 1821495,
  contractAddress: null,
  cumulativeGasUsed: 21612,
  from: "0x3b877e80b5c0b29d88f3768ed4292b35fdd93a9d",
  gasUsed: 21612,
  logs: [],
  root: "31aa355a0a7534b18c7874a31fd78926a6869f0e9e309a972d1b5505405c6421",
  to: "0x5a6661c75df7de88ba74437a6dc372ccfa72a564",
  transactionHash: "0x5fc3f7454d558ad4bd01294448b45bc7072b46958375fafe32e277a770d48e90",
  transactionIndex: 0
}
```

I couldn't find it. Any help? Thx!

Comment: are you looking for the sent input or the returned data?

Comment: The returned data. This function has no input, except for the very msg.sender that comes from the transaction itself.

Answer (score 1):

I guess it is not possible to get the return value of a function when mined asynchronously. According to [How to get return values when function with argument is called?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/3285/how-to-get-return-values-when-function-with-argument-is-called) it is not currently possible to return values from functions which modify the blockchain ... the only way to "return" information is by using Solidity Events.