# Why doesn't the contract return exact value?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, web3js

I wrote a contract source which is just a FIFO queue below:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.0;
contract queue
{
    struct Queue {
        uint256[] data;
        uint256 front;
        uint256 back;
    }
    /// @dev the number of elements stored in the queue.
    function length(Queue storage q) constant internal returns (uint256) {
        return q.back - q.front;
    }
    /// @dev the number of elements this queue can hold
    function capacity(Queue storage q) constant internal returns (uint256) {
        return q.data.length - 1;
    }
    /// @dev push a new element to the back of the queue
    function push(Queue storage q, uint256 data) internal
    {
        if ((q.back + 1) % q.data.length == q.front)
            return; // throw;
        q.data[q.back] = data;
        q.back = (q.back + 1) % q.data.length;
    }
    /// @dev remove and return the element at the front of the queue
    function pop(Queue storage q) internal returns (uint256 r)
    {
        if (q.back == q.front)
            return; // throw;
        r = q.data[q.front];
        delete q.data[q.front];
        q.front = (q.front + 1) % q.data.length;
        return r;
    }
    Queue requests;
    function queue() {
        requests.data.length = 200;
    }
    function addRequest(uint256 d) {
        push(requests, d);
    }
    function popRequest() constant returns (uint256) {
        return pop(requests);
    }
    function queueLength()  constant returns (uint256) {
        return length(requests);
    }
    function hello() constant returns(string s){ 
        return 'hello world!';
    }
}
```

and then I compile it on online compiler https://ethereum.github.io/browser-solidity. I got the contents from the Web3 deploy box, which is :

```
var queue_sol_queueContract = web3.eth.contract([{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"hello","outputs":[{"name":"s","type":"string"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"d","type":"uint256"}],"name":"addRequest","outputs":[],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"queueLength","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"popRequest","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"payable":false,"type":"constructor"}]);
var queue_sol_queue = queue_sol_queueContract.new(
   {
     from: web3.eth.accounts[0], 
     data: '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', 
     gas: '800000'
   }, function (e, contract){
    console.log(e, contract);
    if (typeof contract.address !== 'undefined') {
         console.log('Contract mined! address: ' + contract.address + ' transactionHash: ' + contract.transactionHash);
    }
 })
```

Ok, I click the create button to test it and it works well.
Then I deploy it on my geth but its response isn't good enough:

```
> eth.defaultAccount = eth.accounts[0]
"0x047347096a6dc73f8626afb520c383a02efda314"
> queue_sol_queue.addRequest(2)
I0405 16:19:43.308834 internal/ethapi/api.go:1076] Tx(0xc42776310dde4eb79798ba02f33176bcbb0a8283aa3bb4508af0fd30ed34175e) to: 0x1666d22ba16ff64f94d938301f8ec252f88813a3
"0xc42776310dde4eb79798ba02f33176bcbb0a8283aa3bb4508af0fd30ed34175e"
> queue_sol_queue.addRequest.call(2)
[]
> queue_sol_queue.addRequest.call(2)
[]
> queue_sol_queue.addRequest.call(2)
[]
> queue_sol_queue.popRequest()
0
> queue_sol_queue.popRequest.call()
0
```

it seems that the push can't  push any data and pop can't pop any data ,So how do it work like a FIFO queue? thank you very much.

After getting help from some nice people. I have a new question here:
How to return the value pushed before with only one function? I read some information about events, so I think it may be a solution, but it doesn't return the exact value pushed before.
There is my new source below which added events:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.0;
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// This is an example contract hacked together at a meetup.
// It is by far not complete and only used to show some
// features of Solidity.
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
contract queue
{
    struct Queue {
        uint256[] data;
        uint256 front;
        uint256 back;
    }
    /// @dev the number of elements stored in the queue.
    function length(Queue storage q) constant internal returns (uint256) {
        return q.back - q.front;
    }
    /// @dev the number of elements this queue can hold
    function capacity(Queue storage q) constant internal returns (uint256) {
        return q.data.length - 1;
    }
    /// @dev push a new element to the back of the queue
    function push(Queue storage q, uint256 data) internal
    {
        if ((q.back + 1) % q.data.length == q.front)
            return; // throw;
        q.data[q.back] = data;
        q.back = (q.back + 1) % q.data.length;
    }


    /// @dev remove and return the element at the front of the queue
    function pop(Queue storage q) internal returns (uint256 r)
    {
        if (q.back == q.front)
            return; // throw;
        r = q.data[q.front];
        delete q.data[q.front];
        q.front = (q.front + 1) % q.data.length;
        return r;
    }
    Queue requests;
    event PopEvent(bool ok); //my event designed by me here.(*^__^*) 嘻嘻……
    function queue() {
        requests.data.length = 200;
    }
    function addRequest(uint256 d) {
        push(requests, d);
    }
    function popRequest()  returns (uint256) {
        PopEvent(true);
        return pop(requests);
    }
    function queueLength()  constant returns (uint256) {
        return length(requests);
    }
    function hello() constant returns(string s){ 
        return 'hello world!';
    }
}
```

Hence, can any body help me? thank you!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding `addRequest`: in web3 console, the function call should also specify the `from` argument to tell which account to use for authorizing the trasaction:

```
> queue_sol_queue.addRequest(2, { from: web3.eth.accounts[0] })
```

---

Regarding the `popRequest`: since there is state change for popping the element out of the queue, the function should not be `constant`. You can remove it and try again.

Comment: > queue_sol_queue.addRequest(2, { from: web3.eth.accounts[0] })
I0405 17:20:58.392193 internal/ethapi/api.go:1076] Tx(0xa4d56e43de8f9378493ea4c8ce2f7bb9db4d975a8d7823288ea0c4894299393b) to: 0xc8cf1ea4b0287d559078ad47e12dcc94dd699431
"0xa4d56e43de8f9378493ea4c8ce2f7bb9db4d975a8d7823288ea0c4894299393b"
> queue_sol_queue.popRequest()
I0405 17:22:36.338967 internal/ethapi/api.go:1076] Tx(0x94ed63dbd0b1dd4ff5b6d0a881602b322d517e746c40e197af641dafe517fac6) to: 0xc8cf1ea4b0287d559078ad47e12dcc94dd699431
"0x94ed63dbd0b1dd4ff5b6d0a881602b322d517e746c40e197af641dafe517fac6"
is it works well?

Comment: And what is the return value like :  queue_sol_queue.addRequest(2, { from: web3.eth.accounts[0] })
I0405 17:20:58.392193 internal/ethapi/api.go:1076] Tx(0xa4d56e43de8f9378493ea4c8ce2f7bb9db4d975a8d7823288ea0c4894299393b) to: 0xc8cf1ea4b0287d559078ad47e12dcc94dd699431
"0xa4d56e43de8f9378493ea4c8ce2f7bb9db4d975a8d7823288ea0c4894299393b"

Comment: It seems to be OK, you can check the `queueLength()` to confirm it works. The return value is the transaction address for this function call.

Comment: Thank you very much .but I want to it return the exact value such as popRequest() return the value which is pushed before. How can it do like that ?

Comment: Check this [answer](http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/3293/6429) about the difference between transaction and function calls.

Comment: Can I ask what the purpose is of the modulo operator `% q.data.length` in the likes of `q.back = (q.back + 1) % q.data.length;`?

Comment: That's to model a rotated queue which assumes the elements in queue is always less than the size of the queue so that the space occupied by the front elements can be reused safely.

Comment: thank you for your help. But I want to just only one function to return the value. So what is the solution? I use event in my source, but it doesn't work now.

Comment: Can you create a separate new question with more descriptive details? Thank you!

Comment: I have updated my question here. please help me.thank you.

Comment: I mean to create a new question with more specific issue you'd like to address...

Comment: OK, i have created a new question named How to return a exact value pushed before in my contract?

Comment: I have a new question  here:http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/15076/event-watcher-gives-object-object-in-geth-console, may be you could help me.thanks.

Comment: Hi, I have a question here:  I can use queue_sol_queue.addRequest(2, { from: web3.eth.accounts[0] })
to add the data of 2 to the queue. But where is the 2 stored? is the 2 stored to the blockchain? thank you .

Comment: Yes, it's persist on chain.

Answer (score 0):

As for returning values, you could have a constant function to read followed by the pop to clear it out.
`function getFront() public constant returns (uint) { return request.data[front];}`

From web3.js you can set up a [batch request](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#batch-requests) to call `getFront()` and `pop()` in sequence.

Comment: thank you for your help. But I want to just only one function to return the value. So what is the solution? I use event in my source, but it doesn't work now.