# Event watcher gives [object Object] in Geth console

Tags: solidity, contract-deployment, json-rpc, web3j

I compiled a contract source below:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.0;
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// This is an example contract hacked together at a meetup.
// It is by far not complete and only used to show some
// features of Solidity.
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
contract queue
{
    Queue requests;

    event ElementPopped(uint256 _element); 
    event ElementPushed(uint256 _element, uint256 _index); 

    function queue() {
        requests.data.length = 200;
    }

    struct Queue {
        uint256[] data;
        uint256 front;
        uint256 back;
    }
    /// @dev the number of elements stored in the queue.
    function length(Queue storage q) constant internal returns (uint256) {
        return q.back - q.front;
    }
    /// @dev the number of elements this queue can hold
    function capacity(Queue storage q) constant internal returns (uint256) {
        return q.data.length - 1;
    }

    function isOverlapped(Queue storage q) internal returns (bool) {
        return (q.back + 1) % q.data.length == q.front;
    }

    /// @dev push a new element to the back of the queue
    function push(Queue storage q, uint256 data) internal {
        if (isOverlapped(q)) throw;
        q.data[q.back] = data;

        ElementPushed(data, q.back);

        q.back = (q.back + 1) % q.data.length;
    }


    /// @dev remove and return the element at the front of the queue
    function pop(Queue storage q) internal returns (uint256 r)
    {
        if (q.back == q.front)
            return; // throw;
        r = q.data[q.front];
        delete q.data[q.front];
        q.front = (q.front + 1) % q.data.length;
        return r;
    }


    function addRequest(uint256 d) {
        push(requests, d);
    }

    function popRequest() {
        ElementPopped(pop(requests));
    }

    function queueLength() constant returns (uint256) {
        return length(requests);
    }
}
```

there is a event which is :event ElementPopped(uint256 _element);
I compile the source in https://ethereum.github.io/browser-solidity, I and then paste the contents of Web3 deploy to the geth console.

```
var queue_sol_queueContract = web3.eth.contract([{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"d","type":"uint256"}],"name":"addRequest","outputs":[],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"queueLength","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[],"name":"popRequest","outputs":[],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"payable":false,"type":"constructor"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":false,"name":"_element","type":"uint256"}],"name":"ElementPopped","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":false,"name":"_element","type":"uint256"},{"indexed":false,"name":"_index","type":"uint256"}],"name":"ElementPushed","type":"event"}]);
var queue_sol_queue = queue_sol_queueContract.new(
   {
     from: web3.eth.accounts[0], 
     data: '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', 
     gas: '4700000'
   }, function (e, contract){
    console.log(e, contract);
    if (typeof contract.address !== 'undefined') {
         console.log('Contract mined! address: ' + contract.address + ' transactionHash: ' + contract.transactionHash);
    }
 })
```

Then I type these below in the geth console:

```
> var event = queue_sol_queue.ElementPopped();
undefined
>event.watch(function(error, result){
    // result will contain various information
    // including the argumets given to the Deposit
    // call.
    if (!error)
        console.log(result);
});
{
  callbacks: [function(error, result)],
  filterId: "0x41099921185e90179ba1ac1ff38a91bf",
  getLogsCallbacks: [],
  implementation: {
    getLogs: function(),
    newFilter: function(),
    poll: function(),
    uninstallFilter: function()
  },
  options: {
    address: "0x8bed67280f46cc1ffd401cdb3dd5909f254c8f34",
    from: undefined,
    fromBlock: undefined,
    to: undefined,
    toBlock: undefined,
    topics: ["0xe32433683389a476fe90f93c07386d118310387cc5442554f0f6c2cc839c5942                                                                                        "]
  },
  pollFilters: [],
  requestManager: {
    polls: {
      0x41099921185e90179ba1ac1ff38a91bf: {
        data: {...},
        id: "0x41099921185e90179ba1ac1ff38a91bf",
        callback: function(error, messages),
        uninstall: function()
      }
    },
    provider: {
      newAccount: function(),
      send: function github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/console.(*bridge).Send-fm()                                                                                        ,
      sendAsync: function github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/console.(*bridge).Send                                                                                        -fm(),
      sign: function(),
      unlockAccount: function()
    },
    timeout: {},
    poll: function(),
    reset: function(keepIsSyncing),
    send: function(data),
    sendAsync: function(data, callback),
    sendBatch: function(data, callback),
    setProvider: function(p),
    startPolling: function(data, pollId, callback, uninstall),
    stopPolling: function(pollId)
  },
  formatter: function(),
  get: function(callback),
  stopWatching: function(callback),
  watch: function(callback)
}
```

then:

```
> queue_sol_queue.addRequest(3,   { from: web3.eth.accounts[0] })

"0xe95758f98cda307dc602ff4c6e923a1c61df37a39256436129768bb0d4911d7a"
> queue_sol_queue.addRequest(3,   { from: web3.eth.accounts[0] })
"0x21f70350015d0a3d8200d6fcc11534e66028e5861740d113c54e279266ee3bee"
> queue_sol_queue.addRequest(3,   { from: web3.eth.accounts[0] })
"0x9f2a01aaf63d25dcd9f06b3d2edf65c14a5d44f1bc6d658777b7b68bb6697248"
> queue_sol_queue.addRequest(3,   { from: web3.eth.accounts[0] })
"0x1403a55b839759cc6036790d56d8989d0966013d855bb382db03efff1e5eb5c0"
> queue_sol_queue.popRequest(   { from: web3.eth.accounts[0] })

"0x78225091797345db0810e587425a9f79cb364c4cdb0af60ff2df44eed77a137d"
> [object Object]
> queue_sol_queue.popRequest(   { from: web3.eth.accounts[0] })
"0xc812830b2ed2c6aedbaeb7811cef51dd662eaed1c6ad28855e57571f782648e3"
> [object Object]
```

why it is [object Object]? and how to show the right result? thank you very much .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `result` variable in `console.log(result)` is an object which contains these fields (see the [docs](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#callback-return)):

> Object - An event object as follows:
>
> address: String, 32 Bytes - address from which this log originated.
>
> args: Object - The arguments coming from the event.
>
> blockHash: String, 32 Bytes - hash of the block where this log was in. null when its pending.
>
> blockNumber: Number - the block number where this log was in. null when its pending.
>
> logIndex: Number - integer of the log index position in the block.
>
> event: String - The event name.
>
> removed: bool - indicate if the transaction this event was created from was removed from the blockchain (due to orphaned block) or never get to it (due to rejected transaction).
>
> transactionIndex: Number - integer of the transactions index position log was created from.
>
> transactionHash: String, 32 Bytes - hash of the transactions this log was created from.

These can be accessed by `result.address`, `result.args`, etc.

You can turn the object into a nice string for printing with `console.log(JSON.stringify(result))`

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm wondering how we can assign the value returned by console.log(JSON.stringify(result)) to a variable?