# How to generate a unique random number in web3.js?

Tags: web3js, randomness

I need to generate a unique 128 bit number and know this number in my web3.js script.

Previously I tried [this](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/78859/36438) (create these numbers in my contract and retrieve them to web3.js). It seems impossible.

Now I consider an alternative solution: I instead generate a random number in web.js code and pass it to the contract to be stored in a map.

So the question: How in web3.js to generate a 128 bit random number with almost 100% probability than no other process using my contract generated the same number?

Answer (score 5):

There is a util that can create "cryptographically strong pseudo-random HEX strings from a given byte size." You could then convert this to a number.

`web3.utils.randomHex(size)` --> [documentation](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.0/web3-utils.html)

Per the [github web3js documentation](https://github.com/ethereum/web3.js/blob/efc0a9bc63bd2afe21954ca7ccb986997089370b/docs/web3-utils.rst) the library [frozeman/random](https://github.com/frozeman/randomHex) is used to generate randomness

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
const crypto = require("crypto");
const rand128 = "0x" + crypto.randomBytes(16).toString("hex");
```