# Function returns undefined

Tags: contract-debugging, unittesting, returndata

I have a very simple function in my Solidity contract, that I'm trying to test its return value with Hardhat.

```
    function mintNFT(address _recipient) public returns (uint256)
    {
        uint256 tokenId = calculateTokenID();
        return tokenId;
    }
```

where tokenId has some logic to generate a uint256. I've added a `console.log(tokenId)` in the Smart Contract which correctly prints out the tokenId, however, when returned and attempted to test, it comes back as `undefined`

```
const { expect } = require('chai');

// Import utilities from Test Helpers
const { BN, expectEvent, expectRevert } = require('@openzeppelin/test-helpers');

// Load compiled artifacts
const CONTRACT = artifacts.require('MyContract');

// Start test block
contract('CONTRACT', function ([ owner, other ]) {
  beforeEach(async function () {
    this.contract = await CONTRACT.new();
    await this.contract.initialize();
  });

  it("mintNFT generated a valid token ID", async function () {
    const tokendID = await this.contract.mintNFT();
    expect(tokendID.to.equal(1));
  });
```

Error:

```
  1) Contract: DPC
       mintNFT generated a valid token ID:
     TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'equal')
      at Context.<anonymous> (test/DPC_NFT.js:29:24)
      at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
```

I've even tried hard-coding the function return to a number, and the test still comes back as undefined. Would greately appreciate your help

Comment: not the answer but tx does not return value. So even if it works correctly it will return a tx response and not the token id

Comment: How would you go on about testing something like this? i.e. the returned value of a function?

Comment: @teh0wner The usual solution is to trigger an event and read the event parameters from the transaction receipt. https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/3293/

Answer (score 1):

you are trying to access `to` property on tokenID that is wrong
try this line :

```js
expect(tokenID).to.equal('value you are expect');
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure that await this.contract.mintNFT(); does not return tokenID, it is a transaction