# How can I use "eth_sendTransaction" to invoke a contract and get logs?

Tags: transactions, json-rpc, contract-invocation, events, logs

I have deployed：

```
contract test { 
      function multiply(uint a) returns(uint d) { 
               return a * 7;
      }
}
```

I can call the contract with "**eth_call**" :

```
mpsp@ubuntu-slave2:~$ curl http://10.10.67.217:8545 --data '{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"eth_call","params":[{"to": "0x8e6f99f04148b1fb918cde7e44a94375f94dc745","data":"0xc6888fa10000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000007"},"latest"],"id":1}'
```

the output is:

```
{"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":1,"result":"0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000031"}
```

But when I used "**eth_sendTransaction**" to invoke the contract and after mining, I used "**eth_getTransactionReceipt**" to get the result, and contract seemed not to be invoked.  Here are my steps:

eth_sendTransaction

```
run:       mpsp@ubuntu-slave2:~$ curl http://10.10.67.217:8545 --data '{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"eth_sendTransaction","params":[{"from":"0xc60ec7c68d47814288bdfdaa71b88ff922d735a7","to":"0x8e6f99f04148b1fb918cde7e44a94375f94dc745","gas":"0xC350","gasPrice":"0x1388","data":"0xc6888fa10000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000003"}],"id":1}'
outputs:   {"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":1,"result":"0xcff6d91d1693abe876c25ba03a58bc6ca693078b3a90e836f656e0dddb08a4cd"}
```

eth_getTransactionReceipt

```
run:        curl http://10.10.67.217:8545 --data '{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"eth_getTransactionReceipt","params":["0xcff6d91d1693abe876c25ba03a58bc6ca693078b3a90e836f656e0dddb08a4cd"],"id":1}'
outputs:    {"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":1,"result":{"blockHash":"0x26e23d45caf0c57159e88d9835c573a79f59a4fad0e7a7d70ea7a49780d14448","blockNumber":"0xc3a1","contractAddress":null,"cumulativeGasUsed":"0x5449","from":"0xc60ec7c68d47814288bdfdaa71b88ff922d735a7","gasUsed":"0x5449","logs":[],"root":"c42b14419677df59e3f593fccf03ea28f65bbd8927dcc9239dad6e77eb85f1a3","to":"0x8e6f99f04148b1fb918cde7e44a94375f94dc745","transactionHash":"0xcff6d91d1693abe876c25ba03a58bc6ca693078b3a90e836f656e0dddb08a4cd","transactionIndex":"0x0"}}
```

logs was empty in eth_getTransactionReceipt outputs.

Do you have some suggestions ?

Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The test contract is not emitting an Event, that's why there's no logs.  Return values are not automatically included as a log.

Try:

```
contract test { 
      event R(uint x);
      function multiply(uint a) returns(uint d) { 
               R(a * 7);
               return a * 7;
      }
}
```

In case that doesn't work, you might need to bump up the gas (you have around 28,423 gas left).

Comment: I tried and it worked,thanks a lot! Is there anyway I can get the calculation by using eth_sendTransaction without log

Comment: The return value can be obtained via `eth_call`; or another contract and see http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/765/what-is-the-difference-between-a-transaction-and-a-call for more information.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to using events, if what I really want to do is just to generate log entries in the transaction receipt, I sometime find it simpler to call the "low-level" Solidity logging functions directly:

```
log1( value, 'log_topic');
```

will create a log entry containing `value` with the topic `"log_topic"`.

`log2(value,topic1,topic2)` allows you to create an entry with 2 topics, and so on.

[Link to Solidity documentation](http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/latest/contracts.html#low-level-interface-to-logs)

Comment: it's much simpler ,thank you ! if I don't generate log entries,is there anyway I can get the calculation of the contract?

Comment: You can write it to a contract storage variable after calculating and then later read it directly using `eth_call()`. Writing it to a variable will cost more gas than writing a log entry, but reading it from the contract using `call()` is way simpler and costs no gas.