# geth obscure behavior

Tags: go-ethereum, contract-development

I thought that I had an error similar to [this](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/2086/cannot-perform-write-functions-in-smart-contract-invalid-address) one, that the default account was not set (I was getting method undefined errors for all methods called in my contract).I've set it both in the **geth** console

```
eth.defaultAccount = eth.accounts[0]
```

as well as the js code using **geth**:

```
web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider(`http://${gethServer.host}:${gethServer.port}`));
/*
    Strange bug. Need to specify the account the transactions are made from.
*/
web3.eth.defaultAccount = web3.eth.accounts[0];
```

When calling the methods of this contract:

```
contract C {

     uint[] numbers;

     function initNumbers() {
         numbers.push(1);
         numbers.push(2);
     }

     function stateChanger(uint a) {
         numbers.push(a);
     }

     function getNumber(uint index) returns (uint) {
         if(index >= numbers.length)
            return 0;
         else
            return numbers[index];
     }
}
```

I get the following output in the **geth** console:

```
> c.initNumbers({from:web3.eth.accounts[0],gas:4000000000});
"0x76a1882128d64d94a7bad34e656cd83d57d2a1aefc51b99ba5893f8521a1a79e"
> c.stateChanger(3, {from:web3.eth.accounts[0],gas:400000000});
"0x1b7d5ef5d19a553af756790796a094d2ba213454ab056b7696e2f18e636d8ffc"
> c.stateChanger(4, {from:web3.eth.accounts[0],gas:400000000});
"0xd342a49323b7280e1954a9d33ac9bc457a3015768d5059801d2edf1d16585b9b"
> c.getNumber(0);
"0x31295a2a7ea20cee58e6a144039ae46b835110583b6d1b9517228627eb50999c"
> c.getNumber(1);
"0xce4dba582f37c72d58c767a2b9371a9a8ddbc1e63bc6c96eb5f61cc779168f64"
> c.getNumber(3);
"0x065bd993c4c8e86b2046a53f626619020ad550958dca955a40c839bbc9a1d0c7"
```

Why does **geth** return transaction hashes instead of integers as defined by the contract interface? Is it broken?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `constant` before `returns (unit)` and it will work as expected:

```
function getNumber(uint index) constant returns (uint) {
    if(index >= numbers.length) 
        return 0; 
    else 
        return numbers[index]; 
}
```

The reason why you get a transaction hash is because `geth` is executing your command as a transaction that changes the blockchain.

Comment: Thanks. But what happens when you do try to change the block chain? I have an example that adds an address to an array of addresses and returns true if it did or false if the address is already in the array. When I run the contract I get only the tx hash. Should I use the constant keyword even if the method alters the block chain?

Comment: You cannot use the `constant` keyword for methods that will change the blockchain state. If you want to return a status, you will have to design your contract to save the state and use a constant function to retrieve this saved state. See also [Reading values from a contract: When do I need transactions?](http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/7058/reading-values-from-a-contract-when-do-i-need-transactions) - there is an example `inc()` - there can be multiple transactions of this method in a single block so it does not make sense to get a return status from the state-changing method.

Comment: But is it possible to return a `bool` value in a method that changes the state of the block chain? I've tried with and without the `constant` keyword. Without I get only the tx hash. And with the word I get true but the value is not stored in the block chain as expected. I know this worked before. I'm not sure what happened to geth.

Comment: @Sebi Not possible in the way you're expecting because [the transaction may never get mined](http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/765/what-is-the-difference-between-a-transaction-and-a-call).  You need to [use an Event](http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/4608/how-can-i-use-eth-sendtransaction-to-invoke-a-contract-and-get-logs).  Maybe you were using some testing tool instead of Geth.

Comment: Yes, I was using browser solidity. Thanks for the reply. I have to redesign some of my methods.