# Why contract function return null decoded output in private network?

Tags: contract-development, blockchain, private-blockchain, remix

I am trying to update contract variable value and return value in the same function, It will return value if I deploy it on JavaScript VM but it returns **null** when I deploy contract on **private network**.

**JavaScript VM:**

[image: JavaScript VM]
    **Private Network:**

[image: Private Network]

Am I doing something wrong on my Private Network Setup ? What else could be the possible issue as everything else is entirely the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only a `constant` function returns value to web3 (which is what is used by remixd) on a actual node not Javascript.
If called by another smart contract, though the return value is gotten by the smart contract.

Other Related questions:
https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/7060/1079
[How to get return values when function with argument is called?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/3285/how-to-get-return-values-when-function-with-argument-is-called)
[Reading values from a contract: When do I need transactions?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/7058/reading-values-from-a-contract-when-do-i-need-transactions)
[With web3 how would I get transaction AND function result?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/12841/with-web3-how-would-i-get-transaction-and-function-result/12842#12842)
[What is the difference between a transaction and a call?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/765/what-is-the-difference-between-a-transaction-and-a-call)