# Geth - reading public address[] from contract

Tags: go-ethereum, solidity, javascript, arrays, testrpc

After setting up testrpc and attaching geth:

```
testrpc -a 10
geth attach rpc:http://localhost:8545
```

I initialise the following contract on the geth command line:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.6;
contract AddressList {  
    event addressregistered(address addy);

    uint public NoMembers; 
    address[] public MemberAddresses;

    function registerAddress() { 
        MemberAddresses.push(msg.sender);    
        NoMembers = MemberAddresses.length;    
        addressregistered(msg.sender);
        }  
}

var addresslistContract = web3.eth.contract([{"constant":false,"inputs":[],"name":"registerAddress","outputs":[],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"NoMembers","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"name":"MemberAddresses","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"address"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":false,"name":"addy","type":"address"}],"name":"addressregistered","type":"event"}]);
var addresslist = addresslistContract.new(
   {
     from: web3.eth.accounts[0], 
     data: '0x606060405234610000575b610260806100196000396000f30060606040526000357c0100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000900463ffffffff1680631832425f14610054578063525af8601461006357806392fecc4714610086575b610000565b34610000576100616100e3565b005b34610000576100706101f1565b6040518082815260200191505060405180910390f35b34610000576100a160048080359060200190919050506101f7565b604051808273ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff1673ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff16815260200191505060405180910390f35b6001805480600101828181548183558181151161012c5781836000526020600020918201910161012b91905b8082111561012757600081600090555060010161010f565b5090565b5b505050916000526020600020900160005b33909190916101000a81548173ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff021916908373ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff160217905550506001805490506000819055507feb8ae6c1136c030439e9ea9ffc5cfb3d6daa418c8a5463bc839c4dd4d8382eab33604051808273ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff1673ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff16815260200191505060405180910390a15b565b60005481565b600181815481101561000057906000526020600020900160005b915054906101000a900473ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff16815600a165627a7a723058207e10191d65bf6dfd6a5c15d4fd564ad9b5659a037257ac3d50e20147b3a1fe010029', 
     gas: '4700000'
   }, function (e, contract){
    console.log(e, contract);
    if (typeof contract.address !== 'undefined') {
         console.log('Contract mined! address: ' + contract.address + ' transactionHash: ' + contract.transactionHash);
    }
 })
```

I then store 10 addresses:

```
for (var x = 0; x < 10; x++){
    addresslist.registerAddress({from:eth.accounts[x],gas:3000000}) 
}
```

Finally I attempt to read the MemberAddresses list:

```
> addresslist.MemberAddresses()
"0x50522be14817f1e774e9077f58e7ef4f8d50137f"
```

As you can see, it returns a single address; the first element. If I pass a number it will return that element. I'd like a list. **Can I return all array elements without a loop, on the geth console?**

Comment: There is a answer to your question: http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/9635/4575. You can return 15 objects in one call. And http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/9433/4575: But I assume your defined as: MemberAddresses() constant str{ } where AddressList.call. MemberAddresses() does not charge you any cost.

Comment: @Avatar Thanks, I don't understand how the first link answers my question. It talks about the "call stack process imposing a limitation." Is there something obvious I'm missing?

Comment: Yeah limitation is the answer. You can return 10 values in one call but since there is a limitation you cannot return all array elements in once call if it exceeds the limitation. But using loop won't cost you anything since all State of the contract will stored in the blockchain and if you return value via call().get() it won't cost you. How did you defined your `MemberAddresses()` ?

Comment: @Avatar I defined it as `address[] public MemberAddresses;`

Comment: @Avatar That's only if you return each address as a separate variable in your return tuple. You can just return all the addresses as a single array of addresses

Comment: @TjadenHess you are right, I see the problem by array perspective (created static size array as Node[100]  n;) and iterate array to get the variable at each index as a separate variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just add a getter function

```
function getAddresses() constant returns (address[]){
    return MemberAddresses;      
}
```

Less importantly, convention is to camelCase variables, and capitalize events:

```
event AddressRegistered(address addy);

uint public noMembers; 
address[] public memberAddresses;
```

Note that other contracts will *not* be able to use this function, since dynamic return sizes are not supported in the EVM. You will still be able to use it from web3, though.