# Is is possible to insert objects into an Array at the specified position and shift indexes?

Tags: solidity, arrays

I have following code piece:

```
  struct PaymentReceipt{
    uint   start_block;
    uint   end_block;
  }
  PaymentReceipt[] paymentReceiptList;

  function verfiyPayment(uint block_start, uint block_end) returns (bool success) {
    paymentReceiptList.push(PaymentReceipt({start_block: block_start, end_block: block_end }));
    return true;
  }
```

As I know, each new Struct will be `pushed` on top of the stack, so latest element (`paymentReceiptList.length`) will always point to the latest pushed Struct.

https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/Solidity-Features:

> Dynamically-sized storage arrays have a member function push, such
>   that var l = arr.push(el); is equivalent to arr[arr.length++] = el;
>   var l = arr.length;.

For example, Java has [following approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11638153/2402577) that: we can `insert` the specific element at the specified position in the list.

[Q] Is it possible to push an object into an Array with a given index and shift indexes, like the example on Java?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no built-in method for inserting a value at a specific position in an array. You'll just have to write a loop to do it.

If you're going to be inserting a lot of elements in the middle of the array, it may make more sense to use a linked list instead of an array, so that you aren't doing as many storage writes, which can be expensive.

Comment: I am thinking to implement LinkedList as the implementation in C as via pointer. In order to do that I need to allocate memory space for node and its address. I was not able to obtain its address. `struct node{
    uint   data;
    uint   next;
  }
node head = node(0,0);` is it possible to get head's address in the memory?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you're asking. For a linked list, you need to keep a pointer to the head separate from the rest of the data structure.