# Browsing a mapping variable

Tags: solidity, contract-development, contract-design, mapping

This is my contract where I am building a list of members who will use a `addVote` function. The `allMembersVoted` function always seems to return `false` even though the Remix debugger shows that, the function does return `true` correctly. Can you please help me find out what is missing?

The flow is like this:

- Create new contract
- Build list
- Vote
- Check if every one has voted

  ```
  struct ListMembers {
      bytes32 listOwner;
      bytes32[] members;
  }
  ListMembers public lm;
  mapping(bytes32 => bool) public addedMembers;

  // Constructor to initialise the ListMembers struct
  function Lister(bytes32 listOwner) {
      lm.listOwner = listOwner;
      lm.members.length = 1;
      lm.members[0] = listOwner;
  }

  function buildList(bytes32[] listMembers) {
      lm.members.length = listMembers.length + 1;
      for (uint i = 0; i < listMembers.length; i++) {
          lm.members[i + 1] = listMembers[i];
      }
  }
  function addVote(bytes32 member, uint256 number) {
      if (memberAdded(member) == true) { // Check double votes
          return;
      } else {
          addedMembers[member] = true; // Confirm that vote added
          if (memberIsOwner(member) == true) {
              // Add vote with weight
          } else {
              // Add vote without weight 
          }
      }
  }

  function memberAdded(bytes32 member) returns (bool) {
      return addedMembers[member];
  }

  function allMembersVoted() returns (bool) {
      bool voted = true;
      for (uint i = 0; i < lm.members.length; i++) {
          voted = voted && addedMembers[lm.members[i]];
      }

      return voted;
  }
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, the culprit was the way I was adding to arrays. I changed the addition via index to `push()` and things are working now. So, `lm.members[i + 1] = listMembers[i]` became `lm.members.push(listMembers[i]))`.