# Different return value Truffle & online compiler

Tags: solidity, contract-invocation, truffle, remix

Using the online solidity compiler `startGame()` returns `false`, but using truffle this function returns a long hex string: 0xf697bd4ff4f5574f3cf73cd46a18087a5a0cf1aa1580fd4992ab20f574a808fe

```
function startGame() critical returns (bool) {
    Player player = players[msg.sender];
    if (player.ready) { 
        if (player.balance < minimumwager) { throw; }
            waiting.push(player);
            numWaiting++;
            if (numWaiting > 1) { 
                var thismatchup =  makeMatchup();
                player.playing = true;
                matchupMade(thismatchup); 
                return true; 
            }
            else {
                player.playing = true;
                playerWaiting(player.ethaddress);
                return false; 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You're getting a transaction hash in Truffle.  You need to use events and this overview about transactions could help: http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/765/what-is-the-difference-between-a-transaction-and-a-call

Comment: No problem.  I posted an answer and feel free to edit it or post your own answer that could help others.

Answer (score 1):

Invoking `startGame` with `.call()` in Truffle solved the issue: `startGame.call()`