# What is the array size limit of a returned array from a contract function call in Solidity?

Tags: contract-invocation, parity, gas, arrays, scalability

I have a contract storing rdf data in various mappings. It is all working lovely except for large array returns. I have functions to return arrays of hashes matching certain criteria. I have found, through testing, that a function call to the contract that returns an array of 36,000 bytes32 hashes works fine. However, a function call to the contract that should return an array of 100,000 records fails. An example function I am calling is:

```
// return a bytes32 array of hashes matching a subject search hash
function getSubjectArray(bytes32 which) public constant returns (bytes32[]) {
    return subjectindex[which];
}
```

I was originally testing using web3 function calls to the contract, then I decided to test using direct `curl` commands to see if it was a web3 issue. But it behaves the same using `curl`. A result array of 36,000 hashes returns from the curl call successfully, but a result array of 100,000 returns just `'0x'`.

```
curl --data '{"id":1,"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"eth_call","params":[{"to":"0x0a0bdad3a719adacf6ef29299b25f4799c3961ba","data":"0xd6cf19ffa6ccec97d46345da54fa1ac0a269b860a855d19895705920f2fdfb4eb786817a"},"latest"]}' -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST 127.0.0.1:55200

{"jsonrpc":"2.0","result":"0x","id":1}
```

I have stepped though this large results array using a separate function passing an index, so I know all the 100,000 records are there to be returned. So it seems to be a limit on the size that an array returned from a function call to a contract can be.

Can anyone confirm if there is a limit that an array being returned from a function can be?

Comment: The limit is how much gas is provided, which is needed even for constant functions, so try increasing the `gas`: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/9824/can-solidity-constant-functions-be-arbitrarily-complex

Comment: Apparently my colleague said he was able to get an array of 60,000 hashes from a function call to our RDF storage contract, but not an array of 63,000 hashes.

Comment: There is no gas cost in getting the data. We are not adding any gas. It is just a read. But I can of course try adding some gas I guess. But it pulls 60,000 without any gas just fine. So maybe there is a limit to what is free and at what point it needs gas. I will test adding gas.

Comment: OK I tried adding gas of 4700000 which is the most I can use on our parity network. It made no difference. I still just get back a result of 0x, and no error about being out of gas. I really don't think gas is the issue. It should not cost gas.

Comment: It would be certainly interesting to reproduce this on our side. Could you join the [Parity Gitter](https://gitter.im/paritytech/parity) or create a new [issue on GitHub](https://github.com/paritytech/parity/issues) to discuss this with @tomusdrw and me? Thanks.

Comment: OK. I have joined Parity Gitter

Comment: I have added it to GitHub: https://github.com/paritytech/parity/issues/6293

Comment: I have finally understood the issue of needing to add gas. Sorry for being so slow on the uptake @eth and completely not seeing the link in your reply.

Comment: No problem, I could have been clearer and now we have a reasonably clear answer to this question.

Answer (score 5):

The limit is how much gas is provided: gas is needed even for `eth_call` / constant functions: [Can Solidity constant functions be arbitrarily complex?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/9824/can-solidity-constant-functions-be-arbitrarily-complex)

The `gas` needed to be increased, example in **bold**:

> curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST 127.0.0.1:55200 \
>   --data '{"id":1,"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"eth_call","params": [{"to":"0x0a0bdad3a719adacf6ef29299b25f4799c3961ba","data":"0xd6cf19ffa6ccec97d46345da54fa1ac
>   0a269b860a855d19895705920f2fdfb4eb786817a",
>   **"gas":"0x4000000000000"**},"latest"]}'

---

@tomusdrw from Parity also had a good [explanation](https://github.com/paritytech/parity/issues/6293#issuecomment-322217432) of `eth_call`:

> Yes, reads are indeed free, but eth_call is just creating a "virtual"
>   transaction that gets executed in the context of the blockchain. It's
>   not subject to block gas limit that you tried (4.7M), but still gas
>   calculation is being done for anything that eth_call does (for
>   instance to prevent infinite loop). Our default gas limit was 50M and
>   taking out ~64k of bytes32 was hitting the limit, you should try
>   specifying something much larger like 2**50