# Exceeds block gas limit error to call view functions

Tags: go-ethereum, web3js, truffle, gas-limit, ganache

With solidity view function, you can specific the amount of gas to use. 
My understand is since it is not a state changing transaction, all the gas cost is not charged for, and the client should be able to allow the call function to run with a gas limit larger than the block limit.

According to 
[Can Solidity constant functions be arbitrarily complex?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/9824/can-solidity-constant-functions-be-arbitrarily-complex)
I should be able to pass any amount of gas as a parameter.

However, my truffle & Ganache set up doesn't allow me to do so.

Example: instance.Mymethod.call({gas:900000000})

error: Exceeds block gas limit

Mymethod is a view function.

Can anyone tell me if this is a problem with the Ganache client or is it a legit constraint that read only (view, pure, constant) function should not consume more gas than the block limit?

Thank you,
Tao

Comment: Ganache has a `-l` parameter to specify a gas limit you might try if that helps you https://github.com/trufflesuite/ganache-cli#using-ganache-cli.

Comment: -l specified the block limit. you can increase your block limit, but again read only operation shouldn't subject to block limit constraint

Answer (score 0):

Truffle sucks. I solved it and now can run mocha ganache tests without truffle. [Solidity Exceeds block gas limit during Mocha Tests with Ganache-cli](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/46957/solidity-exceeds-block-gas-limit-during-mocha-tests-with-ganache-cli)