# Unable to add new struct item into mapping or array

Tags: solidity, arrays, mapping

trying to do a sample based on struct, storing a list of struct as a mapping.
but when i add an item and trying to retrieve i cannot find that item in the mapping

below is my contract

```
contract ItemListContract {
    struct  item 
    {
      bytes iname;
      uint16 itemid;
      bytes icode;
      uint ivalue;
    }
    uint itemcount;
    mapping(bytes => item) itemlist;
    item[] itemarray;
    function ItemListContract()
    {
       log0('hi');
    }
    function AddItem(bytes name, uint16 iid, bytes code, uint val)
    {        
       var itemnew = item(name, iid ,code, val);
       log0(itemnew);
       itemlist[code] = itemnew;
       itemarray.push(itemnew);
       itemcount++;
    }
    function countitemlist() returns (uint count)
    {     
      return itemcount;
    }

    function removeitem(bytes code)
    {
    delete itemlist[code];
    itemcount--;
    }
    function getitem(bytes code) returns (bytes iname, uint val)
    {   
      return (itemlist[code].iname,itemlist[code].ivalue);
    }
}
```

I tried to add item by using the below statements

```
var listarrayinterface =[{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"name","type":"bytes"},{"name":"iid","type":"uint16"},{"name":"code","type":"bytes"},{"name":"val","type":"uint256"}],"name":"AddItem","outputs":[],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"code","type":"bytes"}],"name":"getitem","outputs":[{"name":"iname","type":"bytes"},{"name":"val","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[],"name":"countitemlist","outputs":[{"name":"count","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"code","type":"bytes"}],"name":"removeitem","outputs":[],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[],"name":"countitemarray","outputs":[{"name":"count","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"code","type":"bytes"}],"name":"getitemfromarray","outputs":[{"name":"iname","type":"bytes"},{"name":"val","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"payable":false,"type":"constructor"}];
var listarratcontract = eth.contract(listarrayinterface).at("0x62fxxx")
listarratcontract.AddItem.call({data:{name:"item2",iid:2,code:"i2",val:2}})
```

after calling the contract with the above data i got [] as resoponse

Now I tried to query the saved data by

```
listarratcontract.countitemlist.call()
0
```

got response as 0.

when i called using

```
listarratcontract.getitem.call("i2")
["0xo",0]
```

I cant get the saved data or dont even know if the data is saved or not?

can any one point out what the issue might be?

Answer (score 3):

### Summary

The issues are:

1. The default gas for a transaction executing a contract is 90,000 . Your statement to execute `addItem()` does not specify the gas amount so 90,000 is assumed. The execution of this `addItem()` method took 226,554 gas.
2. The `getItem(...)` method should be marked constant to return the values correctly.
3. The `countItemList()` method should also be marked constant to return the value correctly.
4. And as `@Tjaden Hess` commented below, your statement `listarratcontract.AddItem.call({data:{name:"item2",iid:2,code:"i2",val:2}})` does not execute the method as a transaction modifying the blockchain data. See below for the statement to execute this method as a transaction. See [What is the difference between a transaction and a call?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/765/what-is-the-difference-between-a-transaction-and-a-call) for further information.

---

### Details

I've made some minor changes to your source code:

- Formatting.
- Marking `countItemList()` and `getItem(...)` as constant.
- Commenting out `log0(itemnew)` as this statement causes an error in my Browser Solidity / `geth`.

Here is the source code:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.0;

contract ItemListContract {
    struct item {
        bytes iname;
        uint16 itemid;
        bytes icode;
        uint ivalue;
    }

    uint itemCount;
    mapping(bytes => item) itemList;
    item[] itemArray;

    function ItemListContract() {
        log0('hi');
    }

    function addItem(bytes name, uint16 iid, bytes code, uint val) {        
        var itemnew = item(name, iid ,code, val);
        // log0(itemnew);
        itemList[code] = itemnew;
        itemArray.push(itemnew);
        itemCount++;
    }

    function countItemList() constant returns (uint count) {     
        return itemCount;
    }

    function removeItem(bytes code) {
        delete itemList[code];
        itemCount--;
    }

    function getItem(bytes code) constant returns (bytes iname, uint val) {   
        return (itemList[code].iname, itemList[code].ivalue);
    }
}
```

The following screenshot of your code being deployed and executed using Browser Solidity shows that the `addItem(...)` method took 226,554 gas.

[image]

Calling `getItem(...)` returned the value added in the call to `addItem(...)`. And calling `countItemList()` returned 1.

The following section shows the execution of your contract methods using the `geth` command line and the increased gas amount:

```
> var itemListABI = [{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"code","type":"bytes"}],"name":"removeItem","outputs":[],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"countItemList","outputs":[{"name":"count","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[{"name":"code","type":"bytes"}],"name":"getItem","outputs":[{"name":"iname","type":"bytes"},{"name":"val","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"name","type":"bytes"},{"name":"iid","type":"uint16"},{"name":"code","type":"bytes"},{"name":"val","type":"uint256"}],"name":"addItem","outputs":[],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"type":"constructor"}];
undefined
> var itemList = eth.contract(itemListABI).at("0xee7b790b638553cc95a4355d422536bad1566fd7");
undefined
> itemList.addItem("item3", 3, "i3", 3, {from: eth.accounts[0], gas: 500000});
"0xc70469c662c759627c217827845a6567ff1ac1dd2ebd5e0d52fe817aeeb7867a"
> itemList.countItemList()
3
> itemList.getItem("i3")
["0x6974656d33", 3]
```

---

### Gas Cost Differences - Responding To Question In Comments

#### `addItem(...)` Gas Cost Differences

I called `addItem(...)` 4 times with the following parameters and the associated gas cost:

- "item1", 1, "i1", 1 - 226,554
- "item2", 2, "i2", 2 - 196,554
- "item3", 3, "i3", 3 - 196,554
- "item4", 4, "i4", 4 - 196,554

Following is the Browser Solidity screenshot:
[image]

I ran a `debug.traceTransaction(...)` for the first and second operation to find the differences in the gas cost.

Here is a screenshot showing the first difference in gas cost:
[image]

And here is a screenshot showing the second difference in gas cost:
[image]

Here is the code for `addItem(...)`:

```
function addItem(bytes name, uint16 iid, bytes code, uint val) {        
    var itemnew = item(name, iid ,code, val);
    // log0(itemnew);
    itemList[code] = itemnew;
    itemArray.push(itemnew);
    itemCount++;
}
```

The difference in gas cost between the first and second operation is (20,000 x 2) - (5,000 x 2) = 30,000 for the `SSTORE` operation when assigning `itemnew` to `itemList[code]` and `itemArray.push(...)`.

From the fee schedule in the [Ethereum Yellow Paper](http://paper.gavwood.com/), you can see that the first `SSTORE` operation to store the new data in `itemList` and `itemArray` sets the storage value from **zero to non-zero** and costs 20,000 gas (highlighted in green below).

The second `SSTORE` operation to store the new data in `itemList` and `itemArray` sets the storage value from **non-zero to non-zero** and costs 5,000 gas (highlighted in pink below).

[image]

#### `removeItem(...)` Gas Cost Differences

I then called `removeItem(...)` 4 times with the following parameters and the associated gas cost:

- "item1" - 48,181
- "item2" - 48,181
- "item3" - 48,181
- "item4" - 33,181

Following is the Browser Solidity screenshot:
[image]

You can run a `debug.traceTransaction(...)` for the third and fourth operations to find the differences in the gas cost.

Comment: I think the most important thin OP was missing is that `.call` in web3 *simulates* a transaction. They wanted to use an actual transaction

Comment: I observed that gas consumed changing every time i execute the same function, I executed removeItem for 3 times and see different transaction cost and execution cost every time ?                            Result: "0x"
Transaction cost: 24023 gas. 
Execution cost: 26070 gas.

Result: "0x"
Transaction cost: 63046 gas. 
Execution cost: 41070 gas.

Result: "0x"
Transaction cost: 48046 gas. 
Execution cost: 26070 gas.

Comment: I've added a new section to show you the source of the difference in the gas cost for the `addItem(...)` function called the first and second time. You can use the same type of analysis to find the difference in the gas cost for the `removeItem(...)` function called the second-last and the last time. Please ask a new question referencing this Q&A if you have further queries about the gas cost.