# Error: Identifier not found or not unique. when deploying a smart contract which calls another contract

Tags: solidity, contract-invocation, contract-deployment

I am trying to call a contract from another contract.

first contract is the source of items like a data table.
second contract is like a logic layer for the items.

I first deployed the contract1 and got the address, it is working fine.

When I tried to deploy the second contract which has the variable of type contract1 it is throwing the below error when compiling

```
 Error: Identifier not found or not unique.
```

below is my second contact code

```
contract itemlistcallercontract {
     ItemListContract itemlistcontract;
     function itemlistcallercontract()
     {
     itemlistcontract = ItemListContract("0x16c5d0c8fccaf7e5824f5ae25c1662877cec6452");
     }

     function getitemcount() constant returns(int count)
     {
     return itemlistcontract.countItemList();
     }
}
```

i am trying to take the reference of contract1 by passing its address in the contract2 constructor.

But the error is thrown in the declaration of the **itemlistcontract** variable it self.

Cant we call a contract deploying them seperately?
Is there any point I am missing here?

Answer (score 2):

I refer to your code for `ItemListContract` in [Unable to add new struct item into mapping or array](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/10640/unable-to-add-new-struct-item-into-mapping-or-array).

The following code compiles without errors:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.0;

contract ItemListContract {
    struct item {
        bytes iname;
        uint16 itemid;
        bytes icode;
        uint ivalue;
    }

    uint itemCount;
    mapping(bytes => item) itemList;
    item[] itemArray;

    function ItemListContract() {
        log0('hi');
    }

    function addItem(bytes name, uint16 iid, bytes code, uint val) {        
        var itemnew = item(name, iid ,code, val);
        // log0(itemnew);
        itemList[code] = itemnew;
        itemArray.push(itemnew);
        itemCount++;
    }

    function countItemList() constant returns (uint count) {     
        return itemCount;
    }

    function removeItem(bytes code) {
        delete itemList[code];
        itemCount--;
    }

    function getItem(bytes code) constant returns (bytes iname, uint val) {   
        return (itemList[code].iname, itemList[code].ivalue);
    }
}

contract ItemListCallerContract {

     ItemListContract itemListContract;

     function ItemListCallerContract() {
         itemListContract = ItemListContract(0x16c5d0c8fccaf7e5824f5ae25c1662877cec6452);
     }

     function getItemCount() constant returns(uint count) {
         return itemListContract.countItemList();
     }
}
```

In your code, the compiler will need to know the code for `ItemListContract`. The address for the first contract is defined without the double quotes. I also had to change the `getItemCount()` return type to match that of `ItemListContract.countItemList()`.

You can also just provide the interface for the first contract without the implementation details as shown below:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.0;

contract ItemListContract {

    function ItemListContract();

    function addItem(bytes name, uint16 iid, bytes code, uint val);

    function countItemList() constant returns (uint count);

    function removeItem(bytes code);

    function getItem(bytes code) constant returns (bytes iname, uint val);
}

contract ItemListCallerContract {

     ItemListContract itemListContract;

     function ItemListCallerContract() {
         itemListContract = ItemListContract(0x16c5d0c8fccaf7e5824f5ae25c1662877cec6452);
     }

     function getItemCount() constant returns(uint count) {
         return itemListContract.countItemList();
     }
}
```