# How to unmarshall an uint returned from a solidity contract?

Tags: solidity, web3js

I've compiled and deployed the following trivial smart contract:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.7;    
/// Trivial counter contract. Provides an external function which increments the counter
/// and replies the current value.
contract BasicCounter {
    uint private counter = 0;
    function incrementAndGet() external returns (uint) {
        counter++;
        return counter;
    }
}
```

In the `node` REPL I can instantiate a handle for the deployed smart contract:

```
let instance = 
    web3.eth.contract(/* the contract abi */))
        .at(/* the contract address  */);
```

Using the instance, I can invoke the external function `incrementAndGet`:

```
let ret = instance.incrementAndGet();
```

The return value `ret` is a hex string, i.e.

```
0xa768b61d2892dda6495b6b1529e4c81252f333f4ca4ffa18ea7408580366292d
```

If I convert it to a `BigNumber`using `web3`, i.e.

```
let value = web3.toBigNumber(ret);
console.log(`: <${value.toString(10)}>`)
```

I get the following value

```
current counter value: <75721254712088916818789556586747754611065627738232115122133311013811340585261>
```

This looks strange. The first invocation of `incrementAndGet` should rather return something like `00000......00001`.

Any hint what is going wrong here? How to correctly unmarshal an uint value returned from a external function in a smart contract?

Answer (score 4):

The issue is that you can't return a value from a transaction. You can use

```
let ret = instance.incrementAndGet.call();
```

to see view the current counter value.

See [What is the difference between a transaction and a call?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/765/what-is-the-difference-between-a-transaction-and-a-call)