# What is the correct way to access public variable from contract in Truffle: then or standard callback?

Tags: web3js, truffle

There are some similar posts to this but none seem to be able to solve my problem.

I have a contract deployed with Truffle running with testrpc.

I want to access the value of a public uint variable named `gameStatus` defined in the deployed contract `game` variable as such:

```
uint public gameStatus = 23;
```

I have found two ways to do this:

```
game.gameStatus(function(err, res){
    document.getElementById('amt').innerText = res;
});
```

And using the `then` operator from Promises.

```
game.gameStatus().then(function(result){
    document.getElementById('tableamt').innerText = result;
});
```

The first method never affects the value of 'tableamt' in the HTML. And the second method always yields a value of '0' in the HTML.

The contract in both cases deploys without errors and web3 does not complain.

Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried `web3.eth.getCode(contractAddress)` and confirmed the contract is indeed deployed?

Comment: Trying to do that gives me the following error:

Uncaught Error: The MetaMask Web3 object does not support synchronous methods like eth_getCode without a callback parameter.

However when I do game.deployed() I get this:

Contract
BettingOver
:
()
address
:
"0x7881c3a33335a8cceb04b86131f4bf43db26dbd8"
allEvents
:
()
betEnd
:
()
bettingEnd
:
()
bettingStart
:
()

So it looks like the variables are not being set during deploy?

Comment: Then that should do `web3.eth.getCode(contractAddress, function(err, code) { console.log(code);})`

Comment: `web3.eth.getCode("0x7881c3a33335a8cceb04b86131f4bf43db26dbd8", function(err, code){ console.log(code)});
undefined
VM245:1 0x`

Comment: `0x` means there is no code at the address. Of course your "functions" return `0`.

Comment: hmm i see. so you think it's that the function was not deployed correctly?

Comment: I have the following in a file in the migrations/ folder: `module.exports = function(deployer) { deployer.deploy(Modgame, 10, 120, 120); deployer.autolink();};` and when I run `truffle migrate` it says that the migration was done successfully.

Comment: Strange, to me it looks very much like there is a crash in your constructor, or a parent constructor. We need to see code at this stage.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/51967/discussion-between-carlos-g-oliver-and-xavier-lepretre-b9lab).

Answer (score 9):

To get public variable value you need to use [`call`](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#web3ethcall). It is evaluated directly on local node without sending transaction to the blockchain. See also [this great answer](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/770/100).

So, you need to call it that way:

```
game.gameStatus.call(function(err, res){
    document.getElementById('amt').innerText = res;
});
```

Answer (score 8):

It's different now. You should use `contractName.methods.varName().call(callback)` to access state variables in `web3 1.0.0`. Solidity compiler automatically creates getters for public state variables.

To answer your question, the method call should be:

```
game.methods.gameStatus().call(function(err, res){
    //do something with res here
    console.log(res); //for example
};
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple promise works just fine.

```
game.gameStatus().then(function (result) {
    console.log(result);
})
```

*game* is the loaded contact, which in my case, I get with another promise.

```
App.contracts.GameContract.deployed().then(function (game) {
    return game.winningNumbers();
}).then(function (result) {
    console.log(result);
})
```

Answer (score 1):

This

```
(await game.gameStatus()).toString()
```

or this

```
game.gameStatus().then((x) => x.toString())
```

works for me.