# How to access public contract storage with Go?

Tags: go-ethereum, abi, golang

I have a mapping defined in a contract:

```
mapping(bytes32=>string) public name;
```

How can I access this in Go?  `abigen` provides bindings for functions but not variables.  [This question](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/11468/what-is-the-correct-way-to-access-public-variable-from-contract-in-truffle-then) shows how to do this in Javascript but I can't find the equivalent for Go.

Note that I cannot create an `Name()` function as this is a deployed contract not under my ownership.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

abigen supports variables too - but as functions,

from my current code

```
mapping (address => uint256)  public deposits;
```

translates to

```
func (_HelloGoldSale *HelloGoldSaleCaller) Deposits(opts *bind.CallOpts, arg0 common.Address) (*big.Int, error)
```

which you can call via

```
dep, err := saleObject.Deposits(nil,myAddress)
```

Comment: Thank you for this.  Turns out that the ABI itself doesn't contain information on public variables so running `abigen` from the `.sol` file gives different results to running it from the `.abi` file.  The former gives the required functions.