# How is abuse of 'Calls' handled on Ethereum?

Tags: contract-invocation, gas-price

If I read correctly, `Calls` which are read only operations do not cost any gas. Calls can have computing operations. Like currency conversion, loops, etc.

I could for example host a contract with a call that attempts to find number of primes between 1 and 1^100. Any node making a call to this contract would be doing it for free, and spending an awful amount of CPU.

What is the safe guard that Ethereum has put in place to prevent such abuse?

Answer (score 2):

Looks like I over-looked an important piece of information. All `calls` are locally invoked. [What is the difference between a transaction and a call?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/765/what-is-the-difference-between-a-transaction-and-a-call)

Any node making the call will have to spend its own CPU. This does mean that Dapps that are generic or create a Web API proxy for calls to Ethereum must handle this at their end.