# With web3 how would I get transaction AND function result?

Tags: web3js

I'm using testrpc, truffle, and web3 in Node. I've written my contract and pushed it to testrpc with truffle. Here's the gist of the Node code I have so far:

```
let fs = require('fs');
let Web3 = require('web3');
let web3 = new Web3();
let settings = require('./settings.json'); // my own settings file

let abiContractContent = fs.readFileSync(settings.contractAbiPath, 'utf8');
let abi = JSON.parse(abiContractContent);
let contract = web3.eth.contract(abi).at(settings.contractAddress);

web3.eth.defaultAccount = web3.eth.accounts[0];
```

I've then found two ways to call a function in my contract:

```
contract.myFunc(param1, param2, { gas: 200000 });
```

which returns what I believe is the transaction ID for the changes caused by that function call.

```
contract.myFunc.call(param1, param2, { gas: 200000 });
```

which gives me the actual return value of `myFunc`.

I would like to have all of these pieces of information: the transaction AND the return values. I imagine I would need to call my function using the first approach and then look up the return values using the transaction ID but I have no idea how to actually do that. Am I on the right track or should I be looking for an entirely different approach?

Answer (score 11):

> Am I on the right track or should I be looking for an entirely different approach?

Yes, I would say you are on the right track, but you need to know the difference between `call` and `transactions`. Basically:

**Calls:**

- happen locally
- don't cost Ether
- and don't affect the network

**Transactions:**

- are broadcast to the network
- do cost Ether
- and affect the network.

`Call` before you make a `transaction` if you want the result information ASAP. However just remember that call doesn't affect the blockchain, it is basically a local interaction.

You can make a `call` before you make a transaction:

```
var result = contract.myFunc.call(param1, param2, { gas: 200000 });
```

Once you have your result perform the transaction:

```
var txHash = contract.myFunc(param1, param2, { gas: 200000 });
```

---

Also See : [What is the difference between a transaction and a call?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/765/what-is-the-difference-between-a-transaction-and-a-call)

Comment: I would assume that this means the return values from *call* might not be the actual return values of the transaction if another transaction happens in between - so don't rely on them for security!

Answer (score 1):

Answer for using ethers.js:

```js
// this function gets us what the tx at tx_hash returned, 
// and whether it failed or not
async function get_transaction_result(txn_hash, provider){
    const a = await provider.getTransaction(txn_hash);
    try {
        let r = await provider.call(a, a.blockNumber);
        return {'ok':true, 'result': r};
    } catch (err) {
        return {'ok':false, 'result': err};
    }
};

//
// FIND ANSWER HERE
//

// here we execute the contract function and get the transaction
let tx = await contract.functions.myFunc(params, { gas: 200000 })

// here we see what the tx returned and whether it failed or not
let tx_returned = await get_transaction_result(tx.transactionHash, my_provider)
```

Answer (score 0):

As @immibis pointed out and as I replied in the following discussion,
calling a 'sendTransaction' and then fire the '.call()' does not make sense. 
why would you pay for it when you can get it free?

[get the return value of payable function?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/31399/get-the-return-value-of-payable-function/31400#31400)