# function not returning a uint256 while using Hardhat testing

Tags: solidity, ethers.js, hardhat, solidity-0.8.x

Here's the function that's supposed to return a `uint256`

```
function initializeToken(string memory name, string memory symbol) public returns (uint256) {

   // _creatorIds is a @openzeppelin counter
   address creator = msg.sender;
   _creatorIds.increment();
   newId = _creatorIds.current();

   Token token = new Token(symbol, name, creator);
   _tokens[newId] = address(token);
   return newId;
}
```

I followed the testing instructions given [here](https://hardhat.org/tutorial/testing-contracts.html)

The when I console.log() the result in a test file and run it with hardhat it returns a

```
{ Object (hash, blockHash, ...) }
```

instead of a

```
{ BigNumber (_hex, _isBigNumber) }
```

So I can't do any equality tests.

There's probably a really easy answer to this, but I've tried recompiling multiple times, and it still doesn't work.

edit:

Here's the test code as requested:

```
const { expect } = require('chai');

describe("TokenDistributor contract", function() {
    it("Deployment should return a Token with name Test Token and symbol TTN", async function() {
      const [distributor] = await ethers.getSigners();
  
      const TokenDistributor = await ethers.getContractFactory("TokenDistributor");
  
      const instance = await TokenDistributor.deploy();
      await instance.deployed();

      var tokenId = await instance.initializeToken("Test Token","TTN");
      console.log(tokenId); //This is where I did the console.log to see what was wrong
      
      expect(tokenId).to.equal(1); //this is where the test fails
    });
  });
```

Comment: can we see the test code?

Comment: @haxerl sure. I've edited the question body.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Okay, so after fiddling around, I've realized what the problem was. Return value of a non-view/pure functions inaccessible outside of the chain (i.e. other smart-contracts). Hence, to retrieve the return value while returning a function, one must use events instead.

Related question/answer is [here](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/88119) for future reference and for anyone who stumbles upon the same problem.

Comment: OMG thank you! I would never have worked this out on my own...