# Web3JS: Call Smart Contract but where is the data returned?

Tags: contract-development, blocks

I am trying to call a Smart contract that is supposed to return an address.
I have tried the contract in Remix and It all works fine. I am know trying to execute the same contract using We3JS.

To do so I call web3.eth.sendTransaction(), then I wait for the blocked to be mined by comparing transactionReceit.gasUsed < transactionMinedResult.gas. When the block is mined I try to access to the block by calling web3.eth.getBlock(blockHash); It all seems to work and after a few seconds I get my block data back, it looks like this:

```
{
   "blockData":{
      "difficulty":"2004806",
      "extraData":"0xd783010509846765746887676f312e372e33856c696e7578",
      "gasLimit":4712388,
      "gasUsed":44328,
      "hash":"0xdaba1b785abec44f369dd661f457f829acc12ba02ed3e096db71a63801b2e02f",
      "logsBloom":"0x00000000000000000800000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001000080000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000080000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000020000000000000000000000000000000000000010000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001000000000000000000000040000000000000000000000000200000000000",
      "miner":"0x5e5fd76c0ddbf6e594c33cde0c3fa8627d84d116",
      "mixHash":"0xc47e161dcf3f2c3d480bd7dfd5f1a8cbac45582d380d8203bd5a4949f4280fdf",
      "nonce":"0x4ee6e771c2773b25",
      "number":235186,
      "parentHash":"0x5cd9b5db1c3e000faa45ab6e92dae2b678fd00eb84c179f77b4f7fdcf689d047",
      "receiptsRoot":"0xa95a03ebe37e272941e71d357dc10dd57b64c7892bcd303c7cb4fdbd80281083",
      "sha3Uncles":"0x1dcc4de8dec75d7aab85b567b6ccd41ad312451b948a7413f0a142fd40d49347",
      "size":783,
      "stateRoot":"0x2b34eab5aa15aa6502785fb09ea9ae507306be88b0fb9317ab788bbcedd8e28c",
      "timestamp":1492124244,
      "totalDifficulty":"460326490665",
      "transactions":[
         "0xfb214080f50c9fae296b6ec928aeca9c2d3e3a15c33bd5a888845e0aff3950da",
         "0x533638638b9f97b05916a039d0e9da7200f2a1b944cd36294c6c293f0ca064bd"
      ],
      "transactionsRoot":"0xcc4c3f395caaf03b4a98d80cf5578b91fc33f078e4382539daf5824093402fd5",
      "uncles":[

      ]
   }
}
```

Like I said above my contract is returning an address, where can i find this returned data in the block data ?

**EDIT 1**

Here is the contract I am trying to call:

```
address[] public patients;
function getPatientAddress(uint id) public constant returns(address){
    LogPatientAddress(patients[id]);
    return patients[id];
}
```

Following the first answer it is indeed constant, therefore where is the data available from web3js ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Javascript VM in Browser Solidity/Remix will return values to the external environment (like web3.js) for non-constant functions, however this is contrary to behaviour on the actual blockchain where non-constant functions only return a TX receipt to the external environment.

Constant functions eg, `function foo() constant returns(uint)` can return values to both environments.

This may leave a programmer (as in me) wondering why non-constant functions can return values.  The fact is that they can return values to calls made from within the transaction.

So, consider to two following contracts `ak` and `bk`.

```
contract ak {
    uint public a;
    function set(uint val) returns (uint)
    {
        a = val;
        return a;
    }
}
```

If `ak.set(123)` is called by the client, then the state variable `a` is set to the value `123`, but, though the function specifies `return a`, the client only receives the transaction receipt.  For the client to get the actual value of `a` a second call to the public getter `ak.a()` is required.

Contrasting this to an inter-contract call where `bk.set()` calls `ak.set()` and receives an actual return value from `ak.set()` to successfully set `bk.b`.

```
contract bk {
    uint public b;
    function set(address _ak, uint val) returns (uint)
    {
        b = ak(_ak).set(val);
        return b;
    }
}
```

Running this code against an actual blockchain or TestRPC (by selecting Web3 provider in Browser Solidity or Remix) shows that a single client call to `bk.set(<ak_address>,123)` will set both `ak.a` and `bk.b` to the value `123` before returning the transaction receipt to the client but not the value of `bk.b`.

--Edit in response to OP edit--

Even though `getPatientAddress(uint id)` is modified as `constant`, a transaction is still generated because it calls the (presumably) non-constant function `LogPatientAddress(patients[id]);` which overrides the `constant` status.

However as this look like it should be a trivial getter we can simply modify the state variable declaration with `public` which will trigger the compiler to generate a constant getter function for us.

```
uint[] public patientIds;
```

will generate the getter function

```
function patientIds(uint _id) constant returns(uint);
```

Which can then be called from the JS client's contract instance (`k`)

```
var patientID = k.patientIds(<some_Value>);
```

Comment: Ok understood, I have edited my question above with the function I am trying to call, as you can see it is a public constant function, therefore in web3js how could I get the value that this contract is returning ?

Comment: Have updated answer accordingly.  Is `LogPatientAddress(patients[id])` intending to keep a log of all calls made to it?  Is there a reason you need to do this?

Comment: No, not particularly it's just to verify that the contract works when i run it with Remix.

Comment: Are you aware that a Solidity public state variable creates it's own getter function?  So declaring something like `mapping (uint => uint) public patientIds;` will generate the getter function `function patientIds(uint _id) constant returns (uint)`  which will return the value to your client

Comment: I was not no, so instead of having a simple address[] I could just have a mapping (uint => address) public patientIds; ? How then would I access this from web3JS ?

Comment: `uint public patientIDs` works also.  The point is that is one advantage of the `public` keyword`.  It exists as a function defined in the contracts ABI and so you call it like any other function in JS `pId = k.patientIDs(someID)` (where k is you contract instance)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/57095/discussion-between-remi-and-o0ragman0o).

Answer (score 1):

If I understood you correctly you just need to call the function. It's not that complicated:

You said you're using web3js and the function of your contract is (solidity):

```
function getPatientAddress(uint id) public constant returns(address){
    LogPatientAddress(patients[id]);
    return patients[id];
}
```

In order to call this function from web3js the following should be enough (JavaScript):

```
// 1a) Get an object of your contract either by deploying it
var MyContract = MyContract.new([arg1] [, arg2], {data: '0x12345...', from: myAccount, gas: 1000000});

// 1b) or by using an existing intance
var MyContract = web3.eth.contract(abiArray);

// 2) instantiate your contract by address
var contractInstance = MyContract.at([address]);

// call your function and pass your result to a callback:
contractInstance.getPatientAddress.call(id, function(result) {
    // do something with your result
    console.log(result);
});
```

A **transaction** is a write-only operation on the blockchain. If you want to read a value from the blockchain you have to perform a **call**. You might want to look at [this question](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/765/what-is-the-difference-between-a-transaction-and-a-call) for more information about the difference.

The [Web3JS docs](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#web3ethcontract) might help you, too.