# Why does this throw a stack underflow error?

Tags: solidity, eth-call

Simple contract, one function.

```
function getSha256(uint32 nonce) returns (bytes32 hash) {
    return sha256(nonce);
}

> contractInstance.getSha256.call(1);
Error: Error: VM Exception while executing eth_call: stack underflow
```

Comment: this may be related to testrpc ot truffle

Comment: Actually I believe the testrpc issue is the case. The code works fine, but should not be throwing that error. It only happens after I make a back explicit cast and try to run it after making a correction

Comment: open then an issue on their github

Comment: I haven't cornered the STR exactly yet, ty

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding the `constant` modifier as follows:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.10;

contract Test {
    function getSha256(uint32 nonce) constant returns (bytes32 hash) {
        return sha256(nonce);
    }
}
```

And here is the Remix screen showing that it works:

[image]

If you don't add the `constant` modifier, you will have to execute your call as a transaction.

See [What is the difference between a transaction and a call?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/765/what-is-the-difference-between-a-transaction-and-a-call/770#770) for further information.