# Is it possible to reissue the same token symbol after ICO?

Tags: ether, tokens, ico

newbie's here.
For instance, I'm creating a token with symbol "TEST".
In the contract I'm saying that I can sell only 10000 TESTs. Running an ICO, selling this token. But I've got a mistake in my papers. I'm realizing that I need to sell 10000 TESTs more in order to successfully launch my business. What my options are? Is it possible to save tradable symbol TEST with same bids and asks on the exchange and issure more tokens?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Symbol and Names are not unique. As a matter of fact if you do a search on etherscan you will notice there can be several tokens with the same name or symbol. The only thing that makes them unique or identifiable is the address to which they were deployed.
So, technically, you could deploy another token contract with the same name and a different totalSupply and have a new crowdsale that works with that "new token".

What your options are really depend on what was coded on the token contract. For example, is it a mintable token? If it is, are you, as it's owner, able to mint more tokens freely?

You could deploy a new token with a higher supply and transfer the previous tokens to this new contract, as long as they are ERC20 compliant you should be able to do it, at least on the technical side, if your current token holders approve such transactions. You can check this question for more info: [Using Solidity, how can I transfer ERC20 tokens from the current address to another?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/17322/using-solidity-how-can-i-transfer-erc20-tokens-from-the-current-address-to-anot/17337)

It all comes down to how you communicate this to your current investors. From the reasons as to why you will need to do this to what the new address for sending ETH is and instructing them not to use the old one.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Could you please suggest the scenario with `transferFrom`? How should I communicate with investors and what do they need to do? What happens if some of them would reject to _migrate_ to the new token?

Comment: transferFrom function (which is part of the ERC20 specification) allows anyone to transfer x amount of tokens from address _from to address _to.
Of course, before anyone can transfer tokens from my balance to another's I first have to approve it with the approve() function. 
So, one solution would be for you to ask token holders to call approve for their tokens, granting you to transferFrom their balances to a new contract, which should be coded to accept these tokens and add them to its internal balance.
Notice that this would require each token holder to do this and communicate it to you.

Comment: Another solution could be to do a second ICO with TEST2 token and have your dapp accept both TEST and TEST2, and at some future point in time have users change TEST2 for TEST tokens or merge them into a TEST3 token.

Answer (score 1):

Of course you can.
Your token symbol is just field inside the contact source code.

Each client (Mist, Etherscan, Ethereum Wallet, etc) just have method which can look what is inside of symbol variable.

```
string public constant symbol = "TEST";
```

So, you can create as much tokens with symbol "TEST", as you want.

Answer (score 0):

You have a few options:

- If mint function is enabled - you can create the additional 10,000
  TEST tokens to increase the supply up to 20,000 total
- If mint function is not enabled and the contract is not upgradable -
  you must create a new contract and revise the supply to 20,000.  Keep
  in mind you have total and max supply numbers to play with.  If your
  token is already publicly traded and tracked by CoinMarketCap, you
  will need to do a couple of things:
- Inform your community that a new token has been created and that the
  previous token can be migrated over to the new token
- Inform CMC similarly and provide them with the "v2" contract address.

You need to make sure all existing v1 tokens are swapped to v2 - in practice this rarely happens, so you will have two versions of the tokens floating around and both will be tracked by CMC.

You will need to coordinate with all current exchanges and if you're on a DEX, create a new LP with the new token.

Keep it mind, it may have the same symbol, but you're effectively creating an entirely new token.  There's no way to go back and edit/add more tokens unless the contract is mintable.