# how to send usdt to contract

Tags: solidity, web3js

hi can you help me I want to
get tether balance of an account
and send tether to my contract using web3
and send the tether in the contract to another address.
and I have no idea how to do it. I didn't find any tutorial

Comment: Does this https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/17322/using-solidity-how-can-i-transfer-erc20-tokens-from-the-current-address-to-anot work for you?

Answer (score 1):

I think this is the way to transfer USDT or any ERc20 token on any EVM chain with web3JS:-

Step 1: see the code.
e.g. this is USDT (Polygon Matic) solidity code
https://polygonscan.com/address/0x2791bca1f2de4661ed88a30c99a7a9449aa84174#code#L121

step 2: find the function which transfer tokens.
[image: solidity code : aakash4dev]

step 3: get ABI code
most of the trusted NFT-721 give their solidity source code, from there you can get ABI codes.

finally: use web3js .send() methond to interact with that function.

```
let contract = new web3.eth.Contract(ABI, contractadddress)
contract.methods.transferProxyOwnership("0x23498...").send({<gas fee settings>})
        .then(receipt =>console.log(receipt))
        .catch(err=>console.log(err))
```

learn proper web3js from youtube & official docs  https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.11/index.html

Answer (score 0):

here is a solution for you.

1. Use Zapper.fi API to get the USDT balance of an address (Store this).
2. Then use either their API features or plain Web3.js to interact with the USDT smart contract and execute the **transferFrom** function with this as the "_value".

That's it!
I hope this gives you some guidance :)

Comment: hi thanks for your quick answer but i want to know how to interact with USDT contract in solidity. how to use its functions and methods in my solidity contract and get USDT balance of an input address

Comment: Check this:
https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.11/web3-eth-contract.html

Answer (score 0):

I think you must put a deposit function on your contract. You cannot transfer randomly to a contract tokens, it will be reverted, only to address.

Comment: Important correction: it would *not* revert in most cases. Meaning the USDT would be stuck where you sent them, assuming you didn't plan a way to get them out